# How to cut a string after a specific character in unix

Tags: string, shell, unix, sed, awk

So I have this string:

```
$var=server@10.200.200.20:/home/some/directory/file
```

I just want to extract the directory address meaning I only want the bit after the ":" character and get:

```
/home/some/directory/file
```

thanks.

I need a generic command so the cut command wont work as the $var variable doesn't have a fixed length.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using sed:

```
$ var=server@10.200.200.20:/home/some/directory/file
$ echo $var | sed 's/.*://'
/home/some/directory/file
```

Comment: what if the original string had more than one `:` character? Like `$var=server@10.200.200.20:administrators:/home/some/directory/file`. How could we obtain only the last field (the path data)?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, The given command will just work. See http://asciinema.org/a/16807 (because the `.*` will match as much as possible: greedy)

Comment: I like sed commands, which is easier to read!

Answer (score 32):

This might work for you:

```
echo ${var#*:}
```

See [Example 10-10. Pattern matching in parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: +1 Don't mess with cryptic external utilities when the shell has built-in syntax for this. Maybe explore `"${var##*:}"` if you don't need to be portable to older shells. But don't omit the double quotes around variable interpolations unless you are specifically looking for whitespace tokenization.

Comment: @tripleee Nitpicking a little here...s/older shells/non-POSIX shells/. Parameter expansion including `${var#...}` and `${var##...}` is defined by POSIX.

Comment: Pretty useless answer if you don't explain how it works. Explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19482947/1220835

Comment: Note: If there is no match, here no semi-column, then there is no replacement.

Answer (score 25):

This will also do.

```
echo $var | cut -f2 -d":"
```

Answer (score 12):

For completeness, using cut

```
cut -d : -f 2 <<< $var
```

And using only bash:

```
IFS=: read a b <<< $var ; echo $b
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't say which shell you're using.  If it's a POSIX-compatible one such as Bash, then parameter expansion can do what you want:

> ### Parameter Expansion
>
> ...
>
> #### `${parameter#word}`
>
> Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern.
>    The `word` is expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results in `parameter`, with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.

In other words, you can write

```
$var="${var#*:}"
```

which will remove anything matching `*:` from `$var` (i.e. everything up to and including the first `:`).  If you want to match up to the last `:`, then you could use `##` in place of `#`.

This is all assuming that the part to remove does not contain `:` (true for IPv4 addresses, but not for IPv6 addresses)

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick:

```
$ echo "$var" | awk -F':' '{print $NF}'
/home/some/directory/file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' <<< $var
```