# Extract part of a string using bash/cut/split

Tags: string, bash

I have a string like this:

```
/var/cpanel/users/joebloggs:DNS9=domain.example
```

I need to extract the username (`joebloggs`) from this string and store it in a variable.

The format of the string will always be the same with exception of `joebloggs` and `domain.example` so I am thinking the string can be split twice using `cut`?

The first split would split by `:` and we would store the first part in a variable to pass to the second split function.

The second split would split by `/` and store the last word (`joebloggs`) into a variable

I know how to do this in PHP using arrays and splits but I am a bit lost in bash.

Answer (score 486):

To extract `joebloggs` from this string in bash using parameter expansion without any extra processes...

```
MYVAR="/var/cpanel/users/joebloggs:DNS9=domain.example"

NAME=${MYVAR%:*}  # retain the part before the colon
NAME=${NAME##*/}  # retain the part after the last slash
echo $NAME
```

Doesn't depend on `joebloggs` being at a particular depth in the path.

---

**Summary**

An overview of a few parameter expansion modes, for reference...

```
${MYVAR#pattern}     # delete shortest match of pattern from the beginning
${MYVAR##pattern}    # delete longest match of pattern from the beginning
${MYVAR%pattern}     # delete shortest match of pattern from the end
${MYVAR%%pattern}    # delete longest match of pattern from the end
```

So `#` means match from the beginning (think of a comment line) and `%` means from the end. One instance means shortest and two instances means longest.

You can get substrings based on position using numbers:

```
${MYVAR:3}   # Remove the first three chars (leaving 4..end)
${MYVAR::3}  # Return the first three characters
${MYVAR:3:5} # The next five characters after removing the first 3 (chars 4-9)
```

You can also replace particular strings or patterns using:

```
${MYVAR/search/replace}
```

The `pattern` is in the same format as file-name matching, so `*` (any characters) is common, often followed by a particular symbol like `/` or `.`

**Examples:**

Given a variable like

```
MYVAR="users/joebloggs/domain.example"
```

Remove the path leaving file name (all characters up to a slash):

```
echo ${MYVAR##*/}
domain.example
```

Remove the file name, leaving the path (delete shortest match after last `/`):

```
echo ${MYVAR%/*}
users/joebloggs
```

Get just the file extension (remove all before last period):

```
echo ${MYVAR##*.}
example
```

*NOTE:* To do two operations, you can't combine them, but have to assign to an intermediate variable. So to get the file name without path or extension:

```
NAME=${MYVAR##*/}      # remove part before last slash
echo ${NAME%.*}        # from the new var remove the part after the last period
domain
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an argument for or against the creative use of grep, but try it with VAR=/here/is/a/path:with/a/colon/inside:DNS9=domain.com

Comment: Good point, although we could add exceptions that would break almost any solution...  If you were worried you could insert `| tail -n1` after the `grep`.

Comment: Sweet! And it is done inside the executing shell, thereby way faster than the ones using other commands.

Comment: @stolsvik note that some external commands are replaced by builtins (like `echo`).

Comment: This is very useful `NAME=${MYVAR%:*}  # get the part before the colon` However, how do I do the opposite? Like I want to get the part after the colon? I tried moving things around but nothing worked with me.

Comment: @Fadi  You have to switch the wildcard to come before the colon, and use `#` instead of `%`. If you want only the part after the very last colon, use `${MYVAR##*:}` to get the part after the first colon, use `${MYVAR#*:}`

Comment: Friend, you don't know how many times I've come back to this answer. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer!  Question: If my pattern were a variable, would I type it like this `${RET##*$CHOP}` or like this `${RET##*CHOP}` (or another way)?
EDIT: Seems to be the former, `${RET##*$CHOP}`

Comment: Yes with the `$`

Comment: fyi `${MYVAR::3}` expression doesn't work in zsh. Returns `zsh: closing brace expected`. `:3:5` or just `:3` work fine.

Comment: `${MYVAR/search/replace}` is such a nice trick when looping through dates in files in all different formats (yyyy-mm, yyyymm, yyyy/mm).

Answer (score 65):

Define a function like this:

```
getUserName() {
    echo $1 | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs basename
}
```

And pass the string as a parameter:

```
userName=$(getUserName "/var/cpanel/users/joebloggs:DNS9=domain.example")
echo $userName
```

Comment: This answer helped me achieve what I came here for.  There a no accepted answers and this one gets my vote for simplicity.

Comment: The only correction I had to do in the above command was removing the ':', like this `echo $1 | cut -d -f 1 | xargs`. +1 for simple and neat ans.

Comment: Please describe the `cut -d : -f 1 | xargs basename` part of your answer, so that it could be useful to others with similar use cases

Answer (score 28):

What about sed? That will work in a single command:

```
sed 's#.*/\([^:]*\).*#\1#' <<<$string
```

- The `#` are being used for regex dividers instead of `/` since the string has `/` in it.
- `.*/` grabs the string up to the last backslash.
- `\( .. \)` marks a capture group. This is `\([^:]*\)`.

  - The `[^:]` says any character _except a colon, and the `*` means zero or more.
- `.*` means the rest of the line.
- `\1` means substitute what was found in the first (and only) capture group. This is the name.

Here's the breakdown matching the string with the regular expression:

```
        /var/cpanel/users/           joebloggs  :DNS9=domain.example joebloggs
sed 's#.*/                          \([^:]*\)   .*              #\1       #'
```

Comment: Super nice dissection!

Answer (score 18):

Using a single Awk:

```
... | awk -F '[/:]' '{print $5}'
```

That is, using as field separator either `/` or `:`, the username is always in field 5.

To store it in a variable:

```
username=$(... | awk -F '[/:]' '{print $5}')
```

A more flexible implementation with `sed` that doesn't require username to be field 5:

```
... | sed -e s/:.*// -e s?.*/??
```

That is, delete everything from `:` and beyond, and then delete everything up until the last `/`. `sed` is probably faster too than `awk`, so this alternative is definitely better.

Answer (score 12):

Using a single sed

```
echo "/var/cpanel/users/joebloggs:DNS9=domain.example" | sed 's/.*\/\(.*\):.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to chain together awk using different delimitators set with the -F argument. First, split the string on **/users/** and then on **:**

```
txt="/var/cpanel/users/joebloggs:DNS9=domain.com"
echo $txt | awk -F"/users/" '{print$2}' | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

**$2** gives the text after the delim, **$1** the text before it.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late to the party and there's already good answers, but here's my method of doing something like this.

```bash
DIR="/var/cpanel/users/joebloggs:DNS9=domain.example"
echo ${DIR} | rev | cut -d'/' -f 1 | rev | cut -d':' -f1
```

Comment: better late than never my friend.