# Visual Studio Online automatic build version number increment and assembly patching

Tags: azure-devops

i am using for a long time TeamCity.
The *AssemblyInfo patcher* has the ability to patch all assemblyinfo files with a version number that is generated and incremented by TeamCity.
Is this somehow possible with Visual Studio Online Build (the new scriptable, cross-platform one)?

Comment: i just found this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/index

Answer (score 8):

I've created a [Bash Script](https://gist.github.com/apacha/ae6cfe11b8ac35d3389085b7e44a3c82) which automatically replaces the version number in files such as AssemblyVersion.cs and can be used in a build-step, similar to the [Power Shell Script](https://gist.github.com/apacha/e11b12a493393fd25d4fd262c309bff7) published by [Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/scripts/index):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Sample call: ./ApplyVersionToAssemblies.sh ../Source/ AssemblyInfo.cs XamarinAndroid_1.0.0.1

echo "Script to automatically set the version-number in files (e.g. AssemblyInfo.cs)"

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 path_to_search filename build_number"
    exit
fi

# Input is something like XamarinAndroid_1.2.3.4 and we want to extract only the 1.2.3.4
# See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19482947/448357 for more infos
VERSION_NUMBER="${3#*_}"

for file in $(find $1 -name $2); do
    echo "Replacing Version string in $file with ${VERSION_NUMBER}"
    sed -i '' -e 's/"[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"/"'${VERSION_NUMBER}'"/' "$file"
done
```

First, create variables for Major and Minor version
[image]

Second, set the build-number format to `$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Major).$(Minor).$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear).$(Rev:rr)` in the General tab of your build definition

[image]

And finally create a bash-script or a Powershell step with the scripts from above:
[image]