# How to set escape <> symbol Remove text to the right after a delimiter or string

Tags: string, batch-file

Wanted to get string=abc

```
set string=abc[Data]123[USER]Adam
set find=*[Data]

call set wanted=%%string:!find!=%%
echo %wanted%

set wanted=[Data]%wanted%
echo %wanted%

call set JOB_NAME=%%string:!wanted!=%%
echo %JOB_NAME%

output:
123[USER]Adam
[Data]123[USER]Adam
abc
```

Q1
Is there a easy way one line command to remove string to the right after a delimiter was found ?`set find=*[Data]` remove before the delimiter but not after delimiter.Tried to change the wild card to `set find=[Data]*` won't work at all.

Q2
Try to set string in this format `set string=abc<Data>123<USER>Adam` even with escape character `set string=abc^<Data^>123^<USER^>Adam`the system prompt `The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Please explain clearly what you are trying to do instead of leaving us to guess. For instance `this series of instructions` produced `these results` where I expected `these other results`. If you tell us what your ultimate goal is, we may devise another way of reaching it.

Comment: @Magoo I did write on top asking how to get string 123 or remove string to the right if delimiter is found for example `abc<Data>123<USER>Adam` how you remove <USER>ADAM let say if you found <USER>.

Comment: @Magoo I added a few questions and also the change code above.The code  works just that is not the format I want can help ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a `FOR /F` command and specify the `DELIMS=` option with the delimiter you need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Q1

I think you are talking about [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) -- correct me if I am wrong.
There is no reverse thing of `%VARIABLE:*search:replac%`, but there is a nice work-around, supposing the `search` part consists of a single character (`#` in the example below) and it does not appear as the first character in the string:

```dos
set "VARIABLE=test#string"
for /F "delims=# eol=#" %%F in ("%VARIABLE%") do echo(%%F
```

This returns everything in `%VARIABLE%` before the first occurrence of the `#` character. (The `eol=#` portion simply disables the default `eol` character `;`.)

If the delimiter character might also appear at the first position in the string, precede a dummy character temporarily, other than the delimiter (like `_`, for instance):

```dos
set "VARIABLE=test#string"
for /F "delims=#" %%F in ("_%VARIABLE%") do (
    set "VALUE=%%F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!VALUE:~1!
    endlocal
)
```

If the `search` portion consists of multiple characters, things become a bit more complicated, but you could replace it by a single character that does not appear in the part before and use one of the above solutions.

#### Q2

[Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947) already shows the best way to avoid such errors in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40521699).

I want to show you why the escaping failed in your approach:
The escaping like `^<` and `^>` is consumed by setting the variable with `set`. When expanding it like `%VARIABLE%`, it appears unescaped, that is why you receive an error. But -- besides quotation -- there are work-arounds:

```dos
rem // This sets the variable to `abc<Data>123` literally:
set VARIABLE=abc^<Data^>123
rem // This fails as it expands to `abc<Data>123`:
echo(%VARIABLE%

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* This succeeds dueto delayed expansion, because
rem    special characters are no longer recognised then: */
echo(!VARIABLE!
endlocal

rem // This sets the variable to `abc^<Data^>123` literally:
set VARIABLE=abc^^^<Data^^^>123
rem /* This succeeds as it expands to `abc^<Data^>123`,
rem    hence the poisonous characters are escaped properly: */
echo(%VARIABLE%
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question I understand the explanation in Q2 but for Q1 can provide a string example that can be use on your source code cause I can't really visualize .In shell I can remove a part of a string by just using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482123/extract-part-of-a-string-using-bash-cut-split but in batch is kinda complicated .And I saw that it requires two step to remove string right hand side in the sub-string replacement link so I was wondering if there is an eazy way to do it

Comment: I just added test strings (Q1): `set "VARIABLE=test#string"`; the sub-string expansion syntax `echo(%VARIABLE:*#=%` returns `string`, the `for /F` solution returns `test`; is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

The key, I believe, is quoting the strings

Still not clear *WHAT* you want to do, only *how* you've not been able to do it.

Try one or more of these, depending on your preference

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "string=abc<Data>123<USER>Adam"
set "find=*<Data>"

call set "wanted=%%string:%find%=%%"
SET wanted

set "wanted=<Data>%wanted%"
SET wanted

call set "JOB_NAME=%%string:%wanted%=%%"
SET JOB_NAME

ECHO =====================================
set "string=abc<Data>123<USER>Adam"
set "find=*<USER>"

call set "wanted=%%string:%find%=%%"
SET wanted

set "wanted=<USER>%wanted%"
SET wanted

call set "wanted=%%string:%wanted%=%%"
SET wanted

set "find=*<Data>"
call set "JOB_NAME=%%wanted:%find%=%%"
SET JOB_NAME

ECHO =====================================
set "string=abc<Data>123<USER>Adam"
set "find=*<USER>"

call set "JOB_NAME=%%string:%find%=%%"
SET JOB_NAME

ECHO =====================================

set "string=abc<Data>123<USER>Adam"
FOR /f "tokens=1-5delims=<>" %%a IN ("%string%") DO SET "string1=%%a"&SET "string2=%%b"&SET "string3=%%c"&SET "string4=%%d"&SET "string5=%%e"

SET string

GOTO :EOF
```