# Extracting part of a string on jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, substring, jenkins-pipeline

I am having some trouble with the syntax in my pipeline script.

I am trying to capture everything after the last forward slash "/" and before the last period "." in this string git@github.com:project/access-server-pd.git (access-server-pd)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482123/extract-part-of-a-string-using-bash-cut-split) (below) is how I would like to set it up

```
MYVAR="git@github.com:project/access-server-pd.git" 

NAME=${MYVAR%.*}  # retain the part before the colon
NAME=${NAME##*/}  # retain the part after the last slash
echo $NAME
```

I have it current set up with triple quotes on the pipeline script:

```
  stage('Git Clone') {
  MYVAR="$GIT_REPO"
  echo "$MYVAR"
  NAME="""${MYVAR%.*}"""
  echo "$NAME"
```

But I am receiving an unexpected token on "." error. How might I write this so that I can get this to work?

UPDATE: This command does the trick:

```
echo "git@github.com:project/access-server-pd.git" | sed 's#.*/\([^.]*\).*#\1#'
```

Now I just need to find the proper syntax to create a variable to store that value.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing shell code with Groovy code.

Comment: @mkobit Perhaps, in your experience, how would you extract test from a url in Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: For me, I generally try to do some parts of this in the `Jenkinsfile` (which means using the Jenkins subset of supported Groovy features). So in this example, `final beforeColon = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(':'))` stores the result into a `final` variable `beforeColon`. Groovy doesn't need to declare types, but the result is a `String` with the value of `git@github.com`. `final afterLastSlash = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length())` would get everything after the last `/`.

Comment: This is excellent, would you be able to confirm that this is the correct way to do it in my case using variable gitRepo? url="$GIT_REPO"
    final beforeColon = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('.git'))
    url="$beforeColon"
    final gitRepo = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length())

Comment: That looks ok to me, but you should definitely test it. One point of preference to me is to (generally) always use variables like `final gitRepo`, `def gitRepo`, `String gitRepo`, or even `final String gitRepo` instead of just `gitRepo`. If you just use `gitRepo`, that will make it a globally scoped variable to the entire script which can be difficult to debug sometimes. There are also some libraries/tools to test your `Jenkinsfile` if you want to go that direction. In most cases with Jenkins pipelines, it is just a "try until it works" strategy.

Comment: :) You've been extremely helpful! would you mind posting your response, so that I may accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, it looks like using a few Groovy/Java methods on the `String` can extract the parts.

```groovy
final beforeColon = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(':'))  // git@github.com
final afterLastSlash = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length()) // project/access-server-pd.git
```

This uses a few different methods:

- [`public int String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-)
- [`public String String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)
- [`public int String.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--)
- [`public int String.lastIndexOf(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-)

You do need to be careful about the code you use in your pipeline. If it is sandboxed it will run in a protected domain where every invocation is security checked. For example, the [whitelist](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/23fdbbb2ee30f0bec4c77d4a5268949c605c9510/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist) in the [*Script Security Plugin*](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin) whitelists all of the calls used above (for example, [`method java.lang.String lastIndexOf java.lang.String`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/23fdbbb2ee30f0bec4c77d4a5268949c605c9510/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist#L89)).

Performing `String` manipulation in your pipeline code is perfectly reasonable as you might make decisions and change your orchestration based on it.