# Use the Jenkins build log variable ${BUILD_LOG} as a substring in the Post Build Actions

Tags: jenkins

I want to expose the Jenkins build log as part of the Post Build Actions.  Ideally, I just want to use some of the log, and I'm thinking that I can do this by using a substring of what is produced from the build log.

```
${BUILD_LOG, maxLines, escapeHtml}
```

Reference: [How can I take last 20 lines from the $BUILD_LOG variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089096/how-can-i-take-last-20-lines-from-the-build-log-variable)

The reason that I want to use substring over maxlines is because I just want to output some of the log, in this case from `ERROR:`, and the length is variable.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Freestyle, pipeline or multibranch pipeline job?

Answer (score 0):

Doable. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117921/359540) covers off the hurdles / issues you will need to consider and deal with.