# What ##*/ does in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

From the script:

https://gist.github.com/jonnyparris/0a10cc63af281de23a4fd34116fed3e6

I can't figure out what the second line of the snippet below does. I assume it should be a kind of trim.

```
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD | grep -o '[A-Z]\+-[0-9]\+')
BRANCH_NAME="${BRANCH_NAME##*/}"
```

Any reference or explanation would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html under "Substring Removal"

Comment: Refer to highest voted answer of [beroe's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482947/5291015)

Comment: Thank you guys :D