# How to get the current branch within Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm building Docker images with Github Actions and want to tag images with the branch name.

I found the `GITHUB_REF` variable, but it results in `refs/heads/feature-branch-1` and I need only `feature-branch-1`.

Comment: Use this action: https://github.com/EthanSK/git-branch-name-action  it works for both pull_request and push trigger

Comment: IMHO https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210623/680454 should be the accepted answer; it deals with @ambientlight's objection to the currently accepted answer, it avoids use of now-deprecated `setenv`, and it doesn't use any external includes.

Comment: I opened up a [Feature Request](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/5251) with GitHub to add native support for this. Many other CI providers (Travis CI, CircleCI, Semaphore CI) have native support, so there's good precedence for adding something like this. Please upvote the feature request if you'd like to see this behavior added!

Comment: `${{ github.ref_name }}` works for me

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables

Comment: If I need to know the source branch name in case of push (from feature to master branch), which context can be used ? 
Because github.ref_name & github.head_ref are giving master as branch name .

Answer (score 306, accepted):

I added a separate step for extracting branch name from `$GITHUB_HEAD_REF`/`$GITHUB_REF`¹ (pr and push) and set it to the step output:

```yaml
- name: Extract branch name
  shell: bash
  run: echo "branch=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  id: extract_branch
```

after that, I can use it in the next steps with `steps.<step_id>.outputs.branch`:

```yaml
- name: Push to ECR
  id: ecr
  uses: jwalton/gh-ecr-push@master
  with:
    access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    region: us-west-2
    image: eng:${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}
```

---

¹ `$GITHUB_HEAD_REF` on `pull_request` (pr) and `$GITHUB_REF` on `push`. Description:

| Variable | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `GITHUB_HEAD_REF` | The head ref or source branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only set when the event that triggers a workflow run is either `pull_request` or `pull_request_target`. For example, `feature-branch-1`. ([source](https://github.com/github/docs/blob/main/content/actions/learn-github-actions/variables.md)) |
| `GITHUB_REF` | The fully-formed ref of the branch or tag that triggered the workflow run. For workflows triggered by `push`, this is the branch or tag ref that was pushed. For workflows triggered by `pull_request`, this is the pull request merge branch. For workflows triggered by `release`, this is the release tag created. For other triggers, this is the branch or tag ref that triggered the workflow run. This is only set if a branch or tag is available for the event type. The ref given is fully-formed, meaning that for branches the format is `refs/heads/<branch_name>`, for pull requests it is `refs/pull/<pr_number>/merge`, and for tags it is `refs/tags/<tag_name>`. For example, `refs/heads/feature-branch-1`. ([source](https://github.com/github/docs/blob/main/data/reusables/actions/ref-description.md)) |

Full description of these and all other [Default environment variables - Learn Gihtub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) ([archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20230524111325/https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables)).

Looking for the Microsoft Github Action Context named `github`? See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71158878/367456) by [ysfaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6489012/ysfaran) and/or the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59780579/367456) by [Dusan Plavak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599892/dusan-plavak).

Comment: $GITHUB_REF would look like (refs/pull/33/merge), $GITHUB_HEAD_REF would just store the source branch name while $GITHUB_BASE_REF would represent RP destination branch. Maybe you can update your answer to fallback to $GITHUB_HEAD_REF whenever it is set, what do you think?

Comment: GITHUB_HEAD_REF is the head ref, its in the same format, but only for pull requests.

Comment: Shorter version: `run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}"`

Comment: `set-output` has been deprecated now, so the first step should be 

```
- name: Extract branch name
  shell: bash
  run: echo "branch=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})" >>$GITHUB_OUTPUT
  id: extract_branch
```
and can use the `${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}` in the next step as mentioned

Comment: Instead of providing the output via `GITHUB_OUTPUT`, you could also set a environment variable instead. `echo "GIT_BRANCH=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

Answer (score 210):

I believe `GITHUB_REF` is the only environment variable that includes the branch name.

If your branch name does not contain a `/` in it (for example `deploy/abc`), then you can extract just the branch name from the rest of that string like this:

```
${GITHUB_REF##*/}
```

Example:

```
$ GITHUB_REF=refs/heads/feature-branch-1
$ echo ${GITHUB_REF##*/}
feature-branch-1
```

---

**Update: Added a complete workflow example.**

### Workflow

```
name: CI
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Branch name
        run: echo running on branch ${GITHUB_REF##*/}
      - name: Build
        run: docker build -t tedmiston/tag-example:${GITHUB_REF##*/} .
```

Source: https://github.com/tedmiston/x/blob/master/.github/workflows/workflow.yml

### Sample output - master branch

```
Run docker build -t tedmiston/tag-example:${GITHUB_REF##*/} .
  docker build -t tedmiston/tag-example:${GITHUB_REF##*/} .
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
Sending build context to Docker daemon  146.9kB

Step 1/1 : FROM alpine
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
9d48c3bd43c5: Pulling fs layer
9d48c3bd43c5: Verifying Checksum
9d48c3bd43c5: Download complete
9d48c3bd43c5: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:72c42ed48c3a2db31b7dafe17d275b634664a708d901ec9fd57b1529280f01fb
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> 961769676411
Successfully built 961769676411
Successfully tagged tedmiston/tag-example:master
```

Log: https://github.com/tedmiston/x/commit/cdcc58a908e41d3d90c39ab3bf6fef1ad2c4238a/checks#step:4:16

### Sample output - non-master branch

```
Run docker build -t tedmiston/tag-example:${GITHUB_REF##*/} .
  docker build -t tedmiston/tag-example:${GITHUB_REF##*/} .
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
Sending build context to Docker daemon  144.9kB

Step 1/1 : FROM alpine
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
9d48c3bd43c5: Pulling fs layer
9d48c3bd43c5: Verifying Checksum
9d48c3bd43c5: Download complete
9d48c3bd43c5: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:72c42ed48c3a2db31b7dafe17d275b634664a708d901ec9fd57b1529280f01fb
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> 961769676411
Successfully built 961769676411
Successfully tagged tedmiston/tag-example:branch-name-test
```

Log: https://github.com/tedmiston/x/commit/4e8d31259f861aaa2c30375756fc081c3659bddf/checks#step:4:16

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482947/149428) for more on parameter expansion syntax.

For reference the page [Virtual environments for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) lists all of the environment variables available in the execution environment.

Comment: this will work in a shell script but won't work in the workflow YAML file

Comment: @aborilov Are you sure it's not working?  If I understand your goal correctly, it worked for me in the MVP I just created.  I've updated my answer to include the sample workflow yaml code and sample run links for convenience.  Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, this will work for `run` steps, but I also need branch name in ENV vars when I push an image to ECR

Comment: @aborilov I'm not sure that I follow -- the `GITHUB_REF` environment variable should already exist in all of the containers, so you can just read it with the parameter expansion syntax in each place you need it.

Comment: Can I use it here `image: eng:${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}`?
I tried and it's not working for me

Comment: Note that if you use Gitflow-style branch names like `feature/foo`, the `${GITHUB_REF##*/}` syntax will not do what you want: it will strip the `feature/` from the branch name and just return `foo`. I'd recommend using `${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}` instead of `${GITHUB_REF##*/}`, so that `refs/heads/feature/foo` will turn into `feature/foo`. That won't work if your ref is a PR, where instead of `refs/heads/branchname` the value of `$GITHUB_REF` would be `pull/123/merge`... but if your workflow script is expecting a PR, you probably know it (e.g. you're triggering on `pull_request`).

Comment: this didnt work for me. I did `echo "####$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"` but there is no output

Comment: @pyofey Does it work if you use just `echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}` like @rmunn suggested?

Comment: I think this answer has the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-current-branch-within-github-actions/58034787#comment104298828_58035262 - it won't work for pull requests.

Comment: @michielbdejong I see that the question at the top doesn't mention PRs.  For a PR use case, does using `GITHUB_HEAD_REF` in place of `GITHUB_REF` solve the issue for you?  If not, can you provide more concrete info around what you have done (if you have solved this) so I can update the answer?  Docs for that are here - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables.

Comment: Yes! You're right. That solves it for the PR case. And then something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210623/680454 covers both situations. That is what I did in the end, see: https://github.com/solid/node-solid-server/blob/c06c23d/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L24-L32

Comment: We can simply use `GITHUB_REF_NAME` now. Extracting from `GITHUB_REF` isn't needed. More [info](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables).

Answer (score 204):

### TL;DR

This works for every trigger that you can specify under `on` (e.g `push` or `pull_request`):

```yaml
env:
 BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
```

### Explanation

The trick is that `github.head_ref` is only set when the workflow was triggered by a `pull_request` and it contains the value of the source branch of the PR.  `github.ref_name` will than only be used if the workflow was not triggered by a `pull_request` and it also just contains the branch name.

### GitHub Documentation

Detailed explanation from [official GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context):

> **github.ref_name**   `string`    The short ref name of the branch or tag that triggered the workflow run. This value matches the branch or tag name shown on GitHub. For example, feature-branch-1.

> **github.head_ref**   `string`    The head_ref or source branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either pull_request or pull_request_target.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me trying to get the branch name for a github action that is triggered when a new commit is pushed to a pull request.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly when action is triggered by tag (it returns tag name)

Comment: Awesome one-liner solution. Just to note that if the desired was the **target branch** of the pull request, one should set the env `BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.base_ref || github.ref_name }}` instead, because `github.head_ref` returns the source branch (e.g. 'feat/to-be-merged') not the target (e.g. 'main').

Comment: What about `workflow_dispatch` trigger?

Answer (score 182):

Be aware that if you are executing your GitHub action on pull request trigger, then `GITHUB_REF` variable will contain something like `refs/pull/421/merge` so if you will try to `git push` to that name it will most likely fail.

What you can use though are references on the GitHub context in your YAML. Something like: `${{ github.head_ref }}`

https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context

[image: Github action context refs]

Comment: Thanks! FYI this is also available as env var GITHUB_HEAD_REF.

Comment: This answer should be higher in the list.

Comment: Could you modify this answer with an option to work for both cases like `${GITHUB_HEAD_REF-${GITHUB_REF##*/}}`?

Comment: what is this `##*/` syntax

Answer (score 67):

**Update**

GitHub now supports the `GITHUB_REF_NAME`, which stands for: `The branch or tag name that triggered the workflow run`.

GitHub docs on this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

Comment: Which all events is this available for?

Comment: @AnshulSahni I believe it's available for all the events. For those cases where a certain variable is available only for a particular set of events, the docs point to which events. Like with `GITHUB_HEAD_REF`, quoting; "Only set for pull request events. The name of the head branch."

Comment: This is the most relevant answer in 2022!

Comment: You can also use it in the github action with `${{ github.ref_name }}`

Comment: `if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
run: echo "This is a PR for ${{ github.ref_name }}"`

Unfortunately this doesn't print out the branch name :(

My branch name is `feature/foo`, but I get this instead: `This is a PR for 438/merge`

Comment: What if I want the branch name whenever its release/tag which triggers the action ?

Answer (score 51):

Using `setenv` is [now deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/). It is advised to use [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files). Building on @youjin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63387088/90674), while still allowing `feature/`  branches (replacing all occurences of `/` with `-`), I am now using this:

```yml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get branch name (merge)
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        shell: bash
        run: echo "BRANCH_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | tr / -)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Get branch name (pull request)
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        shell: bash
        run: echo "BRANCH_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_HEAD_REF} | tr / -)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Debug
        run: echo ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}
```

Comment: Nice thanks. Beware if working directory is different, it can end up with "Error: No such file or directory". Setting `working-directory: .` should do it in case a different path was set as default.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me. See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/480).

Answer (score 39):

You could use https://github.com/rlespinasse/github-slug-action

```
# Just add this  => 
- name: Inject slug/short variables
  uses: rlespinasse/github-slug-action@v3.x



# And you get this  => 
- name: Print slug/short variables
  run: |
    echo "Slug variables"
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_REF_SLUG }}"    
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_HEAD_REF_SLUG }}"
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_BASE_REF_SLUG }}"
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG }}"
    # output e.g. : master feat-new-feature v1.0.0 product-1.0.0-rc.2 new-awesome-product
    echo "Slug URL variables"
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_REF_SLUG_URL }}"
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_HEAD_REF_SLUG_URL }}"
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_BASE_REF_SLUG_URL }}"
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG_URL }}"
    # output e.g. : master feat-new-feature v1-0-0 product-1-0-0-rc-2 new-awesome-product
    echo "Short SHA variables"
    echo " - ${{ env.GITHUB_SHA_SHORT }}"
    # output e.g. : ffac537e
```

Comment: Thanks. It is very useful for the step which uses action instead of running commands in a shell

Comment: Tried 3-5 different other answers and this one was much easier to use.

Answer (score 26):

For those just finding this thread, you can now use `GITHUB_REF_NAME` e.g. `${{ github.ref_name }}`. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

So if your triggered action workflow branch is `main` this variable will be set to `main`. This is useful if you have multiple repos with `release` and `main` branches, for instance.

Comment: This is the best current answer.

Answer (score 19):

The GitHub Action [FranzDiebold/github-env-vars-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-environment-variables-action) exposes several useful environment variables, such as current branch name and their slug values. I made this action exactly for this use case.

#### Usage

```
steps:
  - uses: FranzDiebold/github-env-vars-action@v1.2.0
  - name: Print environment variables
    run: |
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER"
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_SLUG=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME"
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME_SLUG=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_REF_SLUG=$GITHUB_REF_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_REF_NAME=$GITHUB_REF_NAME"
      echo "GITHUB_REF_NAME_SLUG=$GITHUB_REF_NAME_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_SHA_SHORT=$GITHUB_SHA_SHORT"
```

[image]

A demo for all Operating systems (Linux, macOS and Windows) is also available in the [demo workflows file](https://github.com/FranzDiebold/github-env-vars-action/blob/primary/.github/workflows/demo.yml) of the repository!

Answer (score 18):

> How to get the current branch within Github Actions?

Assuming `${{ github.ref }}` is something like `refs/heads/mybranch`, you can extract the branch name using the following method:

```
steps:
  - name: Prints the current branch name
    run: echo "${GITHUB_BRANCH##*/}"
    env:
      GITHUB_BRANCH: ${{ github.ref }}
```

If your branch includes slashes (such as `feature/foo`), use the following syntax:

```
steps:
  - name: Prints the current branch name
    run: echo "${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}"
```

<sup>Credits: [@rmunn comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-current-branch-within-github-actions#comment102508135_58034787)</sup>

Or use the method from the accepted answer, here is much shorter version (lint friendly):

```
steps:
  - name: Get the current branch name
    shell: bash
    run: echo "::set-output name=branch::${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}"
    id: myref
```

Then refer in other steps as `${{ steps.myref.outputs.branch }}`.

Notes:

- Above methods works only for Unix-based images (Linux and macOS).
- For docs, read: [Context and expression syntax for GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context).

Comment: I like this answer using outputs. Had problems with many of other answers.

Answer (score 18):

```
${{ github.ref_name }}
```

Seems to work fine for for pushes at least. See [ref_name](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) for more details. It says:

> `The branch or tag name that triggered the workflow run.`

Answer (score 14):

To set it as an environment variable, I use this syntax:

```
- name: Extract branch name
  shell: bash
  run: echo "::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed 's/\//_/g')"
- name: Test
  run: echo "${BRANCH_NAME}"
```

I found this syntax here: [Github actions - starter worflows#How to define env variable? #68](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/68#issuecomment-552074596)

*Rmq:* the `sed 's/\//_/g'` is to replace `/` by `_` in the branch name

Comment: Here's how to do it if you're running your step in windows: ```- run: echo ("::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::" + $env:GITHUB_REF.replace('refs/heads/', ''))```. Shell for this command should be powershell which is the default.

Comment: This is deprecated

Comment: Depracated, returns: ``Error: Unable to process command '::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::ci' successfully.
Error: The `set-env` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/
``

Answer (score 12):

Heres a complete workflow that works for both `push` and `pull_request` events

```yaml
name: whichBranch
on: [pull_request, push]

jobs:
  which_branch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch name on push
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        shell: bash
        run: echo "::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
        id: extract_branch

      - name: Extract branch name on pull request
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: echo "::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::$(echo ${GITHUB_HEAD_REF})"

      - name: Print branch name
        run: echo 'The branch name is' $BRANCH_NAME
```

Answer (score 11):

I just made a simple test within *[GitHub Actions](https://github.com/chetabahana/tree/commit/3f391108bceff73c983c69f08526c6fab9e77ca6/checks?check_suite_id=352965999)* using a bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo Reserved for REPO_NAME=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY##*/}
echo GITHUB_REF=${GITHUB_REF}
echo EXTRACT_GITHUB_REF=${GITHUB_REF##*/}
echo EXTRACT_GITHUB_REF_HEADS=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})

cd $REPO_NAME
git checkout ${GITHUB_REF##*/}
git checkout $(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})
```

Here is screenshot of the output:

[image]
So both `${GITHUB_REF##*/}` and `$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})` are correct

Answer (score 6):

If you're using V2 of `actions/checkout` then you can always just run `git branch --show-current` to just get the name of the branch currently checked out.

Answer (score 5):

Now `${{github.ref}}` is the correct way to get branch name.
Please remember `${{github.ref}}` has `refs/heads/..` prefix

Comment: [You can also use `github.ref_name` to get the branch or tag name without the prefix.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context)

Answer (score 4):

Solution to deal with both `pull_request` and `push` events. Implements the workaround to save obtained branch name for further steps, since `set-env` is deprecated.
Doesn't require third-party actions.

```yaml
name: CI
on: [ pull_request, push ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Get branch name and save to env"
        env:
          IS_PR: ${{ github.EVENT_NAME == 'pull_request' }}
        run: |
          if ${IS_PR}; then
            BRANCH_NAME="${GITHUB_HEAD_REF}"
          else
            BRANCH_NAME="${GITHUB_REF##*/}"
          fi
          echo "BRANCH_NAME=${BRANCH_NAME}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: "Another step uses branch name"
        run: echo "Branch name is ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}"
```

[Runtime Variables in GitHub Actions](https://microsoft.github.io/code-with-engineering-playbook/continuous-delivery/devops-provider-recipes/github-actions/runtime-variables/runtime-variables/)

Answer (score 3):

To also deal with the `pull_request` event (in which case the `$GITHUB_REF` contains something not useful like `refs/pull/519/merge`) you can use this one liner:

```
   - name: Set branch name
     run: echo "::set-output name=branch_name::$(echo ${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}})"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use branch name on GitHub actions

Convenience action for using current branch name.
Usage

```
name: build
on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - run: npm ci
    - uses: nelonoel/branch-name@v1
    # Use branch name for whatever purpose
    - run: echo ${BRANCH_NAME}
```

Answer (score 2):

For people using Windows image to run actions, a few key points to know about:

1. It's incorrect to assume that GitHub actions use CMD shell. They [use PowerShell](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-10-17-github-actions-default-shell-on-windows-runners-is-changing-to-powershell/) by default.
2. You can specify the shell to use the following way:

```
- run: |
    ...
  shell: cmd
```

3. You can use the value 'bash' to execute a command in the context of a bash shell.

So, all in all, you don't need to waste potentially hours trying to figure out how to do things in dilapidated cmd way (like I did).

And for the simple purpose of getting the name of the current branch, you can either use the popular solutions while setting the shell to 'bash', or use for example the following simple way to set a variable in the default PowerShell shell:

```shell
$branchName = $Env:GITHUB_REF -replace "refs/heads/", ""
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple to get the current branch and the below code works if the event was triggered by a push event.

`github.ref_name` is a predefined variable to get the branch name.

```
jobs:
  main-branch-build:
    if: github.ref_name == 'main'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
  feature-branch-build:
    if: github.ref_name != 'main'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Comment: if you're here in 2024, you;ll want the updated version of `actions/checkout`, which is currently `actions/checkout@v4` - see also https://github.com/actions/checkout

Answer (score 2):

I've found the best way is to use the [pull_request object](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request) on the [github context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context).

In your workflow yaml:

```
env: 
  PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.number }}
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
  UPDATED_AT: ${{ github.event.pull_request.updated_at }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an action that gets the branch name regardless of pull_request trigger or not. https://github.com/EthanSK/git-branch-name-action

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple git command to get the current branch:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

To get the output in an env file variable simply put:

```
      - name: Set CURRENT_BRANCH
        run: echo "CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

To get the output from the env variable:

```
      - name: Get CURRENT_BRANCH
        run: echo ${{ env.CURRENT_BRANCH}}
```

Source: https://www.techiedelight.com/determine-current-branch-name-git/

Comment: This does not work when operating within a detached head for example, which typically is the case when you're running a github action pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeating here for better visibility what others have written as simple comments in previous replies:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables

The branch name *for pull requests only* is exposed in this environment variable:

`GITHUB_HEAD_REF  Only set for pull request events. The name of the head branch.`

In GitHub actions, the corresponding context key is:

```
github.head_ref
```

Answer (score 1):

This works **locally** (using `git`, not the Github action environment variables) and in *Github actions* in its reincarnations **pull request**, **push** and **merge**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-$(git branch --show-current)}"
```

In a Github action:

```yaml
- run: echo "${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-$(git branch --show-current)}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  shell: bash
  id: branch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/integration' && github.event_name == 'push'
```

You can use the above command and replace whatever branch or event you want to run for.

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 0):

Running on Windows?.
Windows default command is a PowerShell terminal.

```
  - name: SET CURRENT_BRANCH
    run: |
      $branchName = "${{github.ref}}".Split("/")["${{github.ref}}".Split("/").Length -1]
      echo "::set-env name=CURRENT_BRANCH::$(echo $branchName)"
```

Comment: I simply did `$branchName = $Env:GITHUB_REF -replace "refs/heads/", ""`.  I'm not a powershell export, so I'm open to your reasoning

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet which set's an environment variable based on `$GITHUB_REF`, which defaults to `dev` if not present.

Adjust the sed command as per your requirements.

```sh
export GIT_BRANCH=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF:-dev} | sed s/.*\\///g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I always have a script written in either `nodejs` or `python`, which gets invoked from the `workflow.yaml`. The script normally takes care of works like getting proper branch reference.

I have a function like below, in a `prepare-deployment.js` script-

```js
const VALID_REF_PREFIX = 'refs/heads/';
...

function getBranchRef(isProd = false) {
  let branchRef = 'origin/master';

  if (isProd) {
    return branchRef;
  }
  /**
   * When the workflow is invoked from manual flow, the branch name
   * is in GITHUB_REF, otherwise, we have to look into GITHUB_BASE_REF
   */
  if (GITHUB_REF.startsWith(VALID_REF_PREFIX)) {
    // coming from a manual workflow trigger
    branchName = `origin/${GITHUB_REF.replace(VALID_REF_PREFIX, '')}`;
  } else {
    // coming from a PR
    branchRef = `origin/${GITHUB_HEAD_REF}`;
  }

  return branchRef;
}
```

This takes care of the following scenarios-

1. I want to deploy changes from a PR to my dev env
2. I want to deploy changes from any branch I want into my dev env, via a manual trigger
3. I want to deploy changes from master into my prod env

Answer (score 0):

We currently have a separate job, that runs **before** all other jobs. That step determines in what environment it runs, based on the branch name. Our branches are associated with specific environments to deploy infrastructure and code bases. Each environment also has its own secrets (github enterprise feature).

The output environment variable can be used in all other consecutive jobs. You can use that variable within a step, to set it as `NODE_ENV` for example, or tag a docker image with it. You could also set a concurrency on that specific variable to ensure that only a single job or workflow using the same value will run at a time. This makes it very powerful.

Below is an example of what I described above:

```
name: Build pipeline
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/*
      - develop
      - release/*
      - main

jobs:
  environments:
    name: Set environment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "Setting $ENVIRONMENT.."
    outputs:
      # Defaults to 'dev' in case of a feature branch
      # You could also use the contains expression if needed
      environment: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'prd' || (startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/release/') && 'acc' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' && 'tst' || 'dev') }}

  build:
    name: Docker build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [environments]
    environment: ${{ needs.environments.outputs.environment }} # Enterprise only
    concurrency: ${{ needs.environments.outputs.environment }}
    env:
      ENVIRONMENT: ${{ needs.environments.outputs.environment }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Build
        run: |
          docker build . \
            -t hello/world:${{ needs.environments.outputs.environment }}
```

Note: because extracting the environment name is not done in bash or powershell, you are bound to the limited [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#about-expressions) github actions offers. If you need more fancy stuff you could do it differently, there is no single truth. However, I always like to keep things simple and readable.

**Alternative (quick) option**

If you don't mind using other people's github actions, you could use one of the many actions from the marketplace that do a find a replace. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/find-and-replace-strings), that looks like:

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  replace-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: 'Find and replace'
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Remove refs/heads/ from string
        uses: mad9000/actions-find-and-replace-string@1
        id: findandreplace
        with:
          source: ${{ github.ref }}
          find: 'refs/heads/'
          replace: ''
      - name: Branch name
        run: echo "The branch name is ${{ steps.findandreplace.outputs.value }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the ref name on a delete event I ended up using `sed`.

```
on:
  delete:
...
steps:
  - name: Do something
    shell: bash
    run: |
      refname=$(sed -e s:refs/heads/::g -e s:/:-:g <<< ${{ github.event.ref }})
```

cut refs/heads/ and convert slashes to dashes, .e.g. `refs/heads/feature/somefeature` to `feature-somefeature`

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this several different times for events that run on the PR sync event and then on push to main (e.g. building tagged container images) and I don't particularly like:

1. Using 3rd party actions on private repos.
2. Using the expression syntax as I find it to be a rather poor development experience.
3. Having to remember how variable expansion substitution works since I also tend to use `/` separated branches, e.g. `fix/123`.

I thought I would add a small `bash` snippet that will work on push and pull_request events since I didn't see one here:

```
echo "${GITHUB_REF_NAME}" | grep -P '[0-9]+/merge' &> /dev/null && export ref="${GITHUB_HEAD_REF}" || export ref="${GITHUB_REF_NAME}"
```

The `$ref` variable will hold the branch name on push and pull_request events and will handle `gitflow/style/branches`.

This works on the assumption that GH actions creates a (typically unexpected) `{pr number}/merge` branch for actions that run on PR sync, the `grep` call will only return `0` when the branch name matches the (Perl-style) regex and follow the `&&` path to export `ref` as the value of `GITHUB_HEAD_REF`. Or, for branches that don't match the regex (like `main`).

The output redirect on `grep` just prevents the case of a regex match printing to stdout.

Naturally, this won't work if you need the push event on a branch that matches the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$GITHUB_REF_NAME`

Documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but an alternate approach would be to use [tj-actions/branch-names](https://github.com/tj-actions/branch-names).

```yaml
      - name: Get branch name
        id: branch-name
        uses: tj-actions/branch-names@v7
        
      - name: Show the current branch name
        run: |
          echo "Current branch: ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I always see the documentation for the variables provided by GitHub
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts

```
`github.ref_name` and see the document
```

> The short ref name of the branch or tag that triggered the workflow
> run. This value matches the branch or tag name shown on GitHub. For
> example, feature-branch-1.

The one you are using is `github.ref` and the documentation says

> The fully-formed ref of the branch or tag that triggered the workflow
> run.

So it should be `$GITHUB_REF_NAME` instead of `$GITHUB_REF`