# Only run job on specific branch with GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm relatively new to GitHub Actions and I have 2 jobs–one that runs my tests, and one that deploys my project onto a server.

Obviously I want the tests to run on every branch, but deploying should only happen when something gets pushed to master.

I'm struggling to find a way to run a job on a specific branch. I know it's possible to only run *entire workflows* on a specific branch, however that would mean I would have a "test" workflow and a "deploy" workflow.

This sounds like a solution, however they would run parallel. In an ideal world, the tests would run first, and only if they succeed, then the deploy job would start. This isn't the case when using 2 separate workflows.

How would I be able to achieve this? Is it possible to run **jobs** on a specific branch?

Comment: I've updated my answer below with the new `if` conditional at `job` level. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142412/11934042

Comment: This question was asked several years ago and doesn't have an accepted answer. Can I suggest the author accepts one of the quality answers provided below

Answer (score 320):

In a recent update you can now put `if` conditionals at `job` level. See the documentation here. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif

I tested this workflow which runs the job `test` on every push, but only runs `deploy` on the master branch.

```
name: my workflow
on: push
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Execute tests
        run: exit 0
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    steps:
      - name: Deploy app
        run: exit 0
```

What follows is my original answer, and an alternative solution if you prefer to have separate workflows.

The first workflow runs for every branch except `master`. In this workflow you run tests only.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
      - '!master'
```

The second workflow runs for just `master` and runs both your tests and deploys if the tests were successfully passed.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

Comment: You may also want to only run the deploy if the previous jobs succeeded:
`if: success() && github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'`

Comment: Nice answer. Can you please explain the `/refs/heads/...` syntax?

Comment: @Roly It's the format of git references. A ref is just a name that refers to a specific commit in git. It's how branches and tags work. See the [documentation here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References).

Comment: @JanDolejsi checking for `success()` is not necessary: "If your `if` expression does not contain any of the status functions it will automatically result with `success()`." [source](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-status-check-functions)

Comment: Do you know if there is a syntax for comparing  if `github.ref` matches multiple branch names? This `github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging' || …` is a bit verbose, repetitive and long.

Comment: Replaying to myself, with Github Actions this is not straightforward, nevertheless it is possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62419599/2574719.

Comment: Thanks for the '!master' tip above @peterevans.  This helped me improve one of my test workflows today.

Comment: If you want something less verbose, you can use `github.ref_name == 'master'`

Comment: @peterevans can you use `github.ref == 'refs/heads/release/*'` for matching multiple branches here? Or is there any alternative that achieves the same?

Comment: Found it. One could use `startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/head/release/')` for matching multiple branches...

Answer (score 52):

Most answers provide a solution for *one* single branch. To restrict the job to run on **any** specific set of branches, you can do it using the [`if`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif) conditional with multiple disjunction (`||`) operators; but this is too verbose and doesn't respect the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

The same can be archived with less repetition using the [**`contains`**](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#functions) function.

Using `contains`:

```
contains('
  refs/heads/dev
  refs/heads/staging
  refs/heads/production
', github.ref)
```

compared to using multiple `||`:

```
github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/production' || …
```

Full example:

```
---
on: push
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Run tests
      run: …

  deployment:
    name: Deployment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [test]
    if:
      contains('
        refs/heads/dev
        refs/heads/staging
        refs/heads/production
      ', github.ref)
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Deploy
      run: …
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because there is a chance of false positives. Consider a branch "dev" and a branch "device". When using the contains method "dev" will also match "device" and thus run. Even if you didn't intended to. A fix may be to surround github.ref with square brackets and write the branches as [refs/heads/dev].

Comment: That's a good observation and according to the documentation for `contains`, using an array, in fact fixes this sub-string matching behavior.

Comment: Should you update your example to use an array? I don't think array literals are supported yet, but you could use `fromJSON('["val1", "val2"]')`

Comment: [dry is a lie](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/aha-programming)

Answer (score 44):

Here is what I've done for steps that should only run on a specific branch.

```
- name: Publish Image
  # Develop branch only
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop'
  run: |
    ... publish commands ...
```

Answer (score 32):

## 2021 update

> I know it's possible to only run entire workflows on a specific
> branch, however that would mean I would have a "test" workflow and a
> "deploy" workflow.
>
> This sounds like a solution, however they would run parallel. In an
> ideal world, the tests would run first, and only if they succeed, then
> the deploy job would start. This isn't the case when using 2 separate
> workflows.

You can now use the event `workflow_run` to achieve the part `the tests would run first, and only if they succeed, then the deploy job would start` (read on to see how):

**Documentation page of `workflow_run`**

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run

> This event occurs when a workflow run is requested or completed, and
> allows you to execute a workflow based on the finished result of
> another workflow. A workflow run is triggered regardless of the result
> of the previous workflow.
>
> For example, if your pull_request workflow generates build artifacts,
> you can create a new workflow that uses workflow_run to analyze the
> results and add a comment to the original pull request.

Now, considering OP's initial issue:

> I want the tests to run on every branch, but deploying should only happen when something gets pushed to `master`

This now could be solved like this:

*The following setup is working, a few minutes ago I just implemented the same logic in one of my repository*

**Workflow `<your_repo>/.github/workflows/tests.yml`**

```yaml
name: My tests workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request: {}

jobs:
  test:

    # ... your implementation to run your tests
```

**Workflow `<your_repo>/.github/workflows/deploy.yml`**

```yaml
name: My deploy workflow

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: My tests workflow # Reuse the name of your tests workflow
    branches: master
    types: completed

jobs:
  deploy:
    # `if` required because a workflow run is triggered regardless of
    # the result of the previous workflow (see the documentation page)
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}

    # ... your implementation to deploy your project
```

Comment: Also it's important to note that this whole thing with using **workflow_run** filtering and running on specific branch will work ONLY if you push the latest workflow to default branch. Struggled for hours, because I created separate branch **workflow testing** and tested there, but specific workflow were triggered regardless of branch until I pushed it to default 'main'

Comment: Also if I read the docs correctly this *only* works for public repositories.

Comment: @abergmeier seems to work for private repo's as well

Answer (score 13):

Although this discussion is very old but recently I came across the same problem with a slight addition. `if` condition to check whether the branch is `main` works but what if someone pushes their branch and updates the workflow yml file to remove the `if` condition? The deploy job will get triggered without their branch even being reviewed or merged in `main` and could potentially break the production environment. This could be a concern in open source projects.

I couldn't find an answer for this anywhere so wanted to share my findings. I hope this is the right thread for it.

To ensure that there's no way a job is triggered except for in specific branches, [environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) can be used. A deploy job will most likely have some api keys to connect to the destination server that might be stored in secrets. Instead of storing them in repository secrets which are accessible globally within the repository, we should store them in respective environments.

The official docs for environments contain detailed explanation with sample scripts but sharing a simple example here. Let's say we want to run production deployment only when `main` is updated

1. From repository Settings, create a `production` environment
2. Choose `Selected Branches` in `Deployment Branches` dropdown and add `main` in the pattern
3. Add the api keys in production environment secrets

In the workflow yml we just need to add environment information `environment: production` as follows (using script from @peterevans's answer)

```
name: my workflow
on: push
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Execute tests
        run: exit 0
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    environment: production
    steps:
      - name: Deploy app
        run: exit 0
```

The environment information indicates where the secrets have to be read from. If the current branch name doesn't match the pattern provided in `Selected Branches` then the job will immediately fail with an error. Since we have a condition to only run this on `main`, normally that won't bother us because this job will be skipped on other branches anyways. But if someone, mistakenly or with ill intentions, modifies the yml file and removes the condition before pushing their branch, they'll get an error. So, our system remains secure at least from the threat here.

Hope this helps anyone wondering the same.

Answer (score 8):

For steps or jobs you can also use `github.ref_name` which is the branch or tag name that triggered the workflow run.

```
name: my workflow
on: push
jobs:
  if: github.ref_name == 'main'
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Execute tests
        run: exit 0
```

For more information about the github context check [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context).

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me inside a job:

###### Where a PR target branch is one of the following:

```
if: contains(github.base_ref, 'staging')
  || contains(github.base_ref, 'production')
```

###### When the source branch of the pull request is one of them below:

```
if: contains(github.head_ref, 'feature')
  || contains(github.head_ref, 'release')
```

Answer (score 4):

While you can't have conditions at *job* level at this moment, you can have conditions at *step* level - see [Contexts and expression syntax for GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/articles/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#about-context-and-expressions).

For getting a branch name, current solution is to check `GITHUB_REF` environment variable - see [Default environment variables](https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#default-environment-variables) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58033366/11998612) for details.

Putting it all together - if you decide to go with accepted answer in last link, your workflow might look like this:

```
jobs:

 test:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - name: Run tests
    run: ./my-tests.sh

 deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: test
  steps:
  - name: Extract branch name
    shell: bash
    run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF##*/})"
    id: extract_branch
  - name: Deploy
    run: ./deploy.sh
    if: steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch == 'master'
```

If you'd rather keep everything in workflow file instead of separated script, you can always add `if` to each step in given job.

---

I hope it's just a temporary solution/workaround, and job conditions are going to be added before end of beta.

Answer (score 4):

```yaml
name: CI
on: push
jobs:
  prod-check:
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "Deploying to production server on branch $GITHUB_REF"
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#determining-when-to-use-contexts), the if condition is wrapped like so
`if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}`

Answer (score 2):

This works to exit early:

```
  - name: Exit if not on master branch
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    run: exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these two script to the workflows

```
//main.yml
name: main
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main


//size.yml     
name: size
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already some pretty good answers. Here's a way to specify multiple branches in your conditional:

```
name: my workflow
on: push
jobs:
  deploy:
    if: contains(fromJson('["refs/heads/master", "refs/heads/main"]'), github.ref)
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Execute tests
        run: exit 0
```