# Condititionally set Environmental Variable in GitHub Actions Workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to set env variables depending on the branch. I have two branches 'master', and 'develop'. In each case I would like to define the following workflow env varialbes:

```
# for the master branch
env:
  host: test.example.com
  compose_file: docker-compose.staging.yml

# for the develop branch
env:
  host: api.example.com
  compose_file: docker-compose.prod.yml
```

How can I do that?

Currently I have two files which are copies of each other, with only the env variables changed.

I've seen that you can use `${{}}` to evaluate expression. Is that the way to go?

Comment: have two job/steps which each have own env sections then follow this to target which job is run on which branch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139406/only-run-job-on-specific-branch-with-github-actions

Comment: thanks for your reply. Are the env variables set by one job going to persist to the other jobs?

Comment: Variables declared in `jobs.<job_id>.env` only exist for that job, and variables declared in the top-level `env` can't use any fancy logic.

Comment: Ah, I did not find this one. Thanks. Looks like a work-around, but I'll try.