# GitHub Actions - Use `on` to filter by source and target branch for PR

Tags: github-actions

I have an action configured to run an automated test suite on all pull requests to `master`. However, I have a separate release branch called `release/master` that should not trigger the CI, as there's no point in testing it as it only bumps the package version.

The docs don't seem to cover this topic at all though. Is there anyway to filter by target AND source branch at the same time?

Comment: are you merging _from_ `release/master` into `master`, and want to not trigger the workflow in that case? Would predicating the job on an `if` be sufficient, or you're only wondering about workflow initialisation?

Comment: The branch is the trigger, the filtering about the other branch you do in your workflow. What  @Skenvy wrote. This is why you don't find it documented on the trigger docs. Perhaps a feature request, but I doubt it'll get traction.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like. I tried a few forms of `if`, but couldn't make it work, if it's meant to be. I don't see why better trigger logic is "something unlikely to get traction", seems like a pretty basic desire. Splitting up your trigger throughout your script to bail on certain conditions is a pretty poor way to do things.

Comment: Have you checked these answers, they seem very relevant
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139406/only-run-job-on-specific-branch-with-github-actions

Comment: It's a hacky workaround, I suppose that could work for others but it's not suitable for me. Not worth splitting up the filtering conditions and making the entire workflow less clear.

Answer (score 2):

There's *currently* no way to specify a condition on the head branch name at the workflow initialisation (`on`) level. Both `pull_request` and `pull_request_target` use the base branch (the one being merged to) as the branch name checked against in the [`on.<pull_request|pull_request_target>.<branches|branches-ignore>`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore), even though the ref for the [`pull_request_target`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) is the head branch and not the base branch.

The docs for the [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) event suggest that the only available way to limit on the head branch is to `if` the job.

> To run a job based on the pull request's head branch name (as opposed to the pull request's base branch name), use the `github.head_ref` context in a conditional. For example, this workflow will run whenever a pull request is opened, but the `run_if` job will only execute if the head of the pull request is a branch whose name starts with `releases/`:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
jobs:
  run_if:
    if:  startsWith(github.head_ref, 'releases/')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "The head of this PR starts with 'releases/'"
```

In your case you would have to `if` every job in the workflow to run on;

```yaml
if: github.head_ref != 'release/master'
```

Or add it to existing `if`'s you already have;

```yaml
if: >-
  ${{ github.head_ref != 'release/master' && (
  ...) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "paths" filter for workaround, like

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'master'
    paths:
      - '**.js'
```

Based on https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request.
So workflow trigger will be 'target branch is 'master' AND .js files were modified.

If 'it only bumps the package version' modifies only packages.json, workflow is not trigged.

Comment: How is this supposed to help?

Comment: Yeah that's not relevant. This has nothing to do with `.js` files, I'm not sure where in the world you're getting that from?

Comment: A similar answer to this could be tangentially relevant, if your set up included a specific file that only specified the version (for example, as is common in ruby `version.rb` or python `__version__.py`); rather than `if` on not being the `release/master` branch, `paths-ignore`-ing a version file would mean it wouldn't trigger if only that file was changed.