# How to prevent a GitHub action from running outside of main branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow that will be used to deploy production, and I'd like it to be in GitHub as a manually triggered action using `workflow_dispatch`. I added a bit in it to ensure that only authorized people can actually trigger the action, but the issue is that anyone with repository write access can just cut a branch and change that then go and execute the action on their non-main branch via the dropdown window. Is there a way to lock this down to prevent someone from doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only run job on specific branch with GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139406/only-run-job-on-specific-branch-with-github-actions)