# Getting current branch and commit hash in GitHub action

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I want to build a docker image using a GitHub action, migrating from TeamCity.

In the build script, I want to tag the image with a combination of branch and commit, e.g. `master.ad959de`. Testing that locally, I get that information like this:

```sh
git_branch=`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`
git_hash=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
docker_version=${git_branch}.${git_hash}
```

This is the relevant part of the GitHub action:

```
name: CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Create docker image
      run: ./docker-build.sh
```

Running that script in that GitHub action results in this error:

```
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

How can I generate a tag like that inside a GitHub action?

Comment: With the help of the answers below, I was able to create a custom action https://github.com/mindhaq/action-docker-tags

Answer (score 124, accepted):

from [Using environment variables](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/using-environment-variables#default-environment-variables)

github provides two variables that are useful here, you'll need to process them a bit to get the values you desire:

> `GITHUB_SHA`: The commit SHA that triggered the workflow. For example, `ffac537e6cbbf934b08745a378932722df287a53`.

> `GITHUB_REF`: The branch or tag ref that triggered the workflow. For example, `refs/heads/feature-branch-1`. If neither a branch or tag is available for the event type, the variable will not exist.

The short values can be extracted like this:

```
git_hash=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")
git_branch=${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}
```

Comment: Note that if branch name contains `/` git_branch value will be incorrect. For example `ref/heads/actions/test` converts to `test` where as `actions/test` is actual branch name.
Instead use `git_branch=${branch#refs/heads/}` . src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035262/9720375

Comment: Maybe github added some more env vars since this answer was posted; `git_branch` should now be available as `GITHUB_REF_NAME` env var.

Comment: Note that if the trigger of the action is `pull_request` then `${{github.sha}}` is not the latest commit on the branch. See https://github.community/t/github-sha-isnt-the-value-expected/17903

Answer (score 115):

Another approach is to use [github context](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context).

```
- name: Create docker image
  run: ./docker-build.sh ${{ github.head_ref }}.${{ github.sha }}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to add a step to set the values. Note that it uses the full version of the sha (not the short version).

Comment: This should be the correct answer as `${{ github.sha }}` is the correct way to get commit SHA

Comment: @Pietrek It's unreliable as a blanket solution, since [`github.head_ref` is only defined on `pull_request` events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-fallback-value).

Comment: @AbandonedCart I am using ${{github.ref}} actually, but I do not know if that fits your needs

Comment: @Pietrek I use the `$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)` method.

Comment: Keep in mind that this gets you "_the commit SHA that triggered the workflow_", per the docs. If you have a chain of steps that make commits, and/or change `actions/checkout` options like `ref`, this wont necessarily give you the commit you might be expecting, i.e. the latest commit on the branch.

Answer (score 44):

A handy way to get the **currrent branch and commit sha** on the workflow could be getting it and saving on a "variable".

```
  - name: Declare some variables
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo "sha_short=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
      echo "branch=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
  
  - name: Another step
    run: |
      echo "Branch: ${{ env.branch }}"
      echo "Sha: ${{ env.sha_short }}"
```

Maybe your `docker-build.sh` could receive the branch and sha as parameter, os the full version as parameter.

```
  - name: Create docker image
     run: ./docker-build.sh "${{ env.branch }}.${{ env.sha_short }}"
```

OR JUST

```
  - name: Create docker image
     run: ./docker-build.sh "${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}.${GITHUB_SHA}"
```

---

On [this action](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/github-actions-test/blob/master/.github/workflows/env-new.yml) you can see it better.

Comment: `set-output` has been deprecated. The new syntax is described here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files

The new way looks like `echo "SHORT_SHA=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")" >> $GITHUB_ENV`.
Which would add the variable to the environment: `${{ env.SHORT_SHA }}`

Answer (score 9):

Simplest way to get a shortened SHA using [Environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables):

```
- name: Build Docker Image
    run: ./docker-build.sh alpha.${GITHUB_SHA::6}
```

Comment: What is this `alpha.` syntax?

Comment: @Rüdiger it’s a parameter for the build script, most likely a tag for the Docker image. It has nothing to do with the actions syntax, but the evaluation of the expression will result in a parameter like “alpha.ec7ba90” being passed into the build script.

Comment: Shouldn't you change 6→7 to get the 7-digit short SHA?

Comment: What is this `::6` magic at the end? I've never seen this and Github Actions doesn't like it easier: `The workflow is not valid. Unexpected symbol: 'GITHUB_SHA::6'.`

Comment: Just following up, I _think_ this is actually "parameter expansion" and has nothing to do with Github Actions, which makes much more sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it this way in your sh file -

```
BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $GITHUB_REF | cut -d'/' -f 3)
GITHUB_SHA_SHORT=$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | cut -c1-7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Like this

```
name: CI 
on: push 
jobs:   
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Get Branch
      id: branch
      run: echo "git_branch=${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}" >> $GITHUB_BRANCH

    - name: Check Branch
      run: echo "${{ env.branch }}"

    - name: Get Hash
      id: hash
      run: echo "git_hash=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")" >> $GITHUB_HASH

    - name: Check Hash
      run: echo "${{ env.hash }}"

    - name: Create docker image
      run: ./docker-build.sh ${{ env.branch }} ${{ env.hash }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access the SHA for the latest Git commit with `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}`, assuming this is an Action triggered by a Pull Request

Answer (score 1):

Using https://github.com/tj-actions/branch-names provides an output which also works for `push` and `pull_request` events

```yaml
...
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Get branch names
        uses: tj-actions/branch-names@v2.1
        id: branch-names
      
      - name: Current branch name
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}"
        # Outputs: "feature/test" current PR branch.
      
      - name: Current branch name
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}"
        # Outputs: "main" the default branch that triggered the push event.
      
      - name: Get Ref brach name
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.ref_branch }}"
        #  Outputs: "main" for non PR branches | "1/merge" for a PR branch

      - name: Get Head Ref branch name
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.head_ref_branch }}"
        # Outputs: "feature/test" current PR branch.

      - name: Get Base Ref branch name
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.base_ref_branch }}"
        # Outputs: "main" for main <- PR branch.
```