# GitHub Actions GIT_BRANCH environment variable

Tags: git, github-actions

I have a GitHub action running my unit tests for a web app. I run CodeClimate test reporting from this action.

CodeClimate requires two environment variables to be set for the report to be correctly sent. These are;

- GIT_SHA
- GIT_BRANCH

GitHub actions makes the git commit sha avaiable through the github context via `github.sha` so I can set an environment variable on the action like this;

```
env:
    GIT_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
```

However github actions does not make the branch name available.

It does provide a default environment variable called `GITHUB_REF` this is the full ref but I understand that I can grab the short ref i.e. the branch name using this shorthand syntax `$GITHUB_REF##*/`

The problem I have is that I cannot set an env variable called GITHUB_BRANCH with this value `$GITHUB_REF##*/`

Does anyone how I might get the branch name and set it to the environment variable `GIT_BRANCH` so the CodeClimate test script would be able to use it.

Ultimately I want my env config to look like this:

```
env:
    GIT_SHA: <git commit sha>
    GIT_BRANCH: <current git branch>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting current branch and commit hash in GitHub action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886293/getting-current-branch-and-commit-hash-in-github-action)

Comment: (so tl;dr, you don't need to do any special environment setup in github actions, the variables are already there)

Comment: The variables are there correct, however not under the name that CodeClimate requires. Add it seems you cant set an environment based on the value of another.

Comment: `${{ env.GITHUB_BRANCH }}` for example should work

Comment: It looks like setting `GIT_BRANCH: ${{ github.head_ref }}` may work. Although not sure this will work for a push to the main branch as that would be on the push event and not the pull_request event

Comment: @AnthonySottile GITHUB_BRANCH is not an environment variable that is already available

Answer (score 9):

> Ultimately I want my env config to look like this:
>
> ```
> env:
>    GIT_SHA: <git commit sha>
>    GIT_BRANCH: <current git branch>
> ```

You can achieve the same effect (setting the environment variables) not only in the workflow definition but by setting the variables dynamically in a dedicated workflow step. You can do it by [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) and [built-in `GITHUB_SHA` and `GITHUB_BRANCH` variables](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables):

```yaml
jobs:
  set-env:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set environment variables
        run: |
          echo "GIT_SHA=${GITHUB_SHA}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "GIT_BRANCH=${GITHUB_REF##*/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Use environment variables
        run: |
          echo "GIT_SHA=${GIT_SHA}"
          echo "GIT_BRANCH=${GIT_BRANCH}"
```

Executing the workflow should give you the output:

[image]

Comment: this is extremely helpful but very buried in the answer `${GITHUB_REF##*/}`

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, rather than using GITHUB_REF, it could be useful to use GITHUB_HEAD_REF or GITHUB_BASE_REF to figure out the real branch names (above all, if workflow is associated to a PR):

Examples of output:

```
    GITHUB_REF="refs/pull/4/merge"
    GITHUB_BASE_REF="main"
    GITHUB_HEAD_REF="key_advertisement"
```

More information here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context