# How can i get the date of a commit in github actions workflow

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, workflow, cicd

I would like to know if there is any way to get the date of a commit through an environment variable or something to be able to use it within github actions.

Comment: You can find all default env vars here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

Comment: @Dominik there are no references to date or timestamp there or at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts Does this mean it doesn't exist?

Comment: If it's not in the docs it's a good guess for it not to be a public API yeah

Answer (score 2):

similar to @trayan-azarov

```bash
_GIT_COMMIT_DATE=$(git log -1 --format=%cd --date=format:%Y%m%dh%H%M%S)
```

this just gives you greater flexibility with the date format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using git for this e.g.:

```
export COMMIT_TIME=$(git show -s --format=%ci dd28288f)
```

Where `dd28288f` is your commit sha (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58886352 for more info). Or you can use the GitHub built-in env vars - `${GITHUB_SHA::8}`

The above will result in `COMMIT_TIME=2023-02-25 19:59:02 +0200`

Hope this helps.