# How to get short Github SHA of the `main` branch in Github Actions?

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

I want to get a short Git SHA for the main branch in my Github actions workflow.

I referred to [multiple answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886293/getting-current-branch-and-commit-hash-in-github-action) but their SHA commit is (be it GITHUB environment or the git command) of the branch that triggered the workflow. I want the last short commit of the Github main branch. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're triggering the action on a pull request, then `github.event.pull_request.base.sha` is the current SHA of the `HEAD` of the
PR's target branch. You can use that variable for the full SHA, or get a shortened SHA by passing that to `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse --short ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}
```

If you aren't triggering on a pull request, or if you want to hedge against the chance that somebody might open a PR against a different branch, then you'll need to do something a little more complicated:

```
git ls-remote -q | grep refs/heads/main$ | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git rev-parse --short
```

(use `refs/heads/master$` if your default branch is named `master`, or `refs/heads/production$` if it's named `production`, etc.)

Comment: I did this: ```git fetch --prune --unshallow
          export MAIN_BRANCH_SHA_SHORT=$(git rev-parse --short origin/main)
          echo "::set-output name=MAIN_BRANCH_SHA_SHORT::$MAIN_BRANCH_SHA_SHORT"```

Comment: "grep + awk" can be shortened to just awk: `awk '/refs\/heads\/main$/{print $1}'`.