# How to get pull request number within GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to access the Pull Request number in a Github Actions workflow. I can access the `GITHUB_REF` environment variable that is available. Although on a Pull Request action it has the value: `refs/pull/125/merge`. I need to extract just the `125`.

I have found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-current-branch-within-github-actions) that shows how to get the current branch using this variable. Although in this case, what I am parsing is different and I have been unable to isolate the Pull Request number.

- I have tried using `{GITHUB_REF##\*/}` which resolves to `merge`
- I have also tried `{GITHUB_REF#\*/}` which resolves to `pull/125/merge`

I only need the Pull Request number (which in my example is 125)

Comment: If the event is a `pull_request`, you should be able to use `${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}`. See all of the attributes here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#get-a-pull-request

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Although it is already answered, the easiest way I found is using the github context. The following example shows how to set it to an environment variable.

```
env:
  PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.number }}
```

Comment: This solution is good because the one above gives deprecation warnings form github actions, also this is a short 2 liner as well

Comment: But I GUESS this only works when the action is filtered on only pull requests, for example if the action is triggered by an issue, the event.number will be the issue's one.

Comment: @ObayAbd-Algader, actually, it looks like to be just for PRs, issues will be inside github.event.issue.number. I didn't find any documentation of this behaviour (yet)

Answer (score 13):

An alternative if you are trying to figure out which PR a commit is linked to on a `push` instead of a `pull_request` event is to use the `gh` CLI [which is included in the standard GitHub Action images](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md#cli-tools).

For example:

```yaml
      - name: Get Pull Request Number
        id: pr
        run: echo "::set-output name=pull_request_number::$(gh pr view --json number -q .number || echo "")"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Be sure to add [`pull_request: read` permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions) on the job as well.

Then in following steps, you can access it with the variable,

```
${{ steps.pr.outputs.pull_request_number }}
```

Comment: I tried your implementation, but the `gh cli` didn't recognised the repo without adding the `actions/checkout` to the job steps. Once I added it, it worked as expected ! Thanks for sharing. I quoted your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101736/grabbing-pr-number-from-a-push-event)

Answer (score 8):

While the answer by @Samira worked correctly. I found out that there is a new way to do this and wanted to share it with anyone who might stumble upon this.

The solution is to add a stage at the beginning of your workflow which gets the PR number from the Github Token (event) and then set it as an environment variable for easy use throughout the rest of the workflow. Here is the code:

```
  - name: Test
    uses: actions/github-script@0.3.0
    with:
      github-token: ${{github.token}}
      script: |
        const core = require('@actions/core')
        const prNumber = context.payload.number;
        core.exportVariable('PULL_NUMBER', prNumber);
```

Now in any later stage, you can simply use $PULL_NUMBER to access the environment variable set before.

Answer (score 7):

How about using `awk` to extract parts of `GITHUB_REF` instead of bash magick?

From `awk` manpage:

> -F fs
>
> --field-separator fs
>
> Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).

As long you remember this, it's trivial to extract only part of variable you need. `awk` is available on all platforms, so step below will work everywhere:

```
- run:   echo ::set-env name=PULL_NUMBER::$(echo "$GITHUB_REF" | awk -F / '{print $3}')
  shell: bash
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working snippet to get the issue number in both `push` and `pull_request` events within a GitHub Actions workflow by leveraging [actions/github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script):

```js
steps:
  - uses: actions/github-script@v6
    id: get_issue_number
    with:
      script: |
        if (context.issue.number) {
          // Return issue number if present
          return context.issue.number;
        } else {
          // Otherwise return issue number from commit
          return (
            await github.rest.repos.listPullRequestsAssociatedWithCommit({
              commit_sha: context.sha,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
            })
          ).data[0].number;
        }
      result-encoding: string
  - name: Issue number
    run: echo '${{steps.get_issue_number.outputs.result}}'
```

The script queries the [list labels for an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/labels#list-labels-for-an-issue) REST API endpoint via [octokit/rest.js](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#repos-list-pull-requests-associated-with-commit) client.

Answer (score 4):

For actions that need to run on PRs and on comments on PRs, I ended up extracting it with:

```
export PR_NUMBER="${{ github.event.pull_request.number || github.event.issue.number }}"
```

This is because `github.event.pull_request.number` is only defined for events triggered by a PR opening/closing, while `github.event.issue.number` is only defined for comments on PRs (the former needs a `on: pull_request`, the latter needs a `on: issue_comment`): this method allowed me to recycle the same action across different workflows.

Answer (score 3):

In my case my job is trigged by

```
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
```

so using `github.event.number` doesn't give me the PR number.

The other solutions here are all using the deprecated `set-env` method which require you to "allow unsecure commands"

I was able to successfully put the PR into my env variables using a more modern method w/ `awk` (I took that part from Samarai's answer):

```
      - name: Get Pull Request Number
        run: echo "PULL_NUMBER=$(echo "$GITHUB_REF" | awk -F / '{print $3}')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        shell: bash
```

Then using it in other steps is simply:
`${{ env.PULL_NUMBER }}`

Comment: We need more documentation like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just gonna drop what worked out for me

```
      - id: find-pull-request
        uses: jwalton/gh-find-current-pr@v1
        with:
          # Can be "open", "closed", or "all".  Defaults to "open".
          state: open
      - name: create TODO/FIXME comment body
        id: comment-body
        run: |
          yarn leasot '**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}' --ignore 'node_modules/**/*' --exit-nicely --reporter markdown > TODO.md
          body="$(sed 1,2d TODO.md)"
          body="${body//'%'/'%25'}"
          body="${body//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
          body="${body//$'\r'/'%0D'}" 
          echo "::set-output name=body::$body"
      - name: post TODO/FIXME comment to PR
        uses: peter-evans/create-or-update-comment@v2
        with:
          issue-number: ${{ steps.find-pull-request.outputs.number }}
          body: ${{ steps.comment-body.outputs.body }}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a Github Action that runs on pushes only, so to get the PR number from our pull request merges to `main`, I used a combination of Samira and Pete's answers:

```
  - name: Get PR number
    id: pr
    run: echo "::set-output name=pull_request_number::$(echo "${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}" | awk -F"[\#)]" '{print $2}')"
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This uses `awk` to get the PR number from the commit message which on a PR merge looks like so:

[image]

We can then retrieve the value in any step afterwards with `${{ steps.pr.outputs.pull_request_number }}`

Hope this helps.