# How to Define Github Branch Specific Secret or an Alternative?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, environment-variables, travis-ci

For example, travis-ci.com allows the user to define an env variable which is bound to a certain branch. Whereas Github does allow you to define secret env variables, they, however, all have to compete for the same namespace which introduces additional complexity. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: This is the only thing which prevents me from fully migrating to Github Actions.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can create an [environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) on GitHub. And you can [create secrets for that environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-an-environment). And finally, you can add a [deployment branch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#deployment-branches) for that environment. That means you could have a job to [deploy to that environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#using-an-environment) using that secret. Only that job would have access to the secret and you can also set a rule to only allow deploys to that environment using workflows on that branch.

I think, that way you get what you want (or maybe a little bit more restrictive) because only that branch would have access to the secret but you have to define an environment. I suppose in most cases when you introduce a secret that depends on a branch it's because that branch represents an environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen that particular feature, which means you need to define your variable environment with a naming convention:

```
branchName_myVariable
```

In your GitHub Action script, you can then reference said variable by prepending the [branch name you would have extracted in a separate step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035262/6309).

Answer (score 0):

I defined `staging` and `prod` environments in GitHub and defined secret for each of them.

GitHub Environments:

- staging

  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=project-staging
- prod

  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=project-production

Then I use the following GitHub workflow script to activate specific environment depending on the branch:

```
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'prod' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging' && 'staging' }}
```

Finally using the secret.

```
- name: Deploy Cloud Functions
  run: |
    npx firebase-tools use ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
    npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions --json
```