# Get push source branch name in GitHub action

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub action workflow where I am doing a merge of various different source branches into target branch main.

When I look at GITHUB_REF it contains main branch.

How do I get the name of the source branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get branch name on GitHub action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300169/how-to-get-branch-name-on-github-action)

Comment: Thanks for the link - I had already read this as post as part of my search, it doesn’t answer my question since it shows how to get the target branch name - I want to get the source branch name.

Answer (score 0):

To have access to all the properties of the event that triggered the action, you can look-up the path in the variable `$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH` (it's a json describing the event).

You can then access it using `${{ github.event.<the path in the json> }}`. In your case `${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}` should have the info you are looking for.

Potential duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331829/how-to-get-the-target-branch-of-the-github-pull-request-from-an-actions/62332270#62332270)?