# How to get branch name for tagged build on GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to push docker images to Docker Hub on tagged commits on the master branch.

Everything I've tried ([How to get branch name on GitHub action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300169/how-to-get-branch-name-on-github-action), lots of action plugins, like https://github.com/tj-actions/branch-names) only give me the tag name, but I need to know the branch name.

Specifically what I want to do is push a docker image to docker hub *on tagged commits on master branch*.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I understood why this was not possible: When running a build based on the tagging event, the git checkout is not on a branch at all (it is a detached head).

It is possible to *find* the branch though, using `git branch -a --contains <tag name>` and a full checkout (`fetch-depth: 0`).

```
  docker_tagged:
    name: Tagged - Docker push to tag based on git tag. Also push 'latest' if on master
    needs: tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: startsWith(github.event.ref, 'refs/tags')
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - run: echo "TAG=${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}" | tee -a $GITHUB_ENV
      - run: echo "BRANCH=$(git branch -a --contains ${{ env.TAG }} | grep -v HEAD | cut -d '/' -f3)" | tee -a $GITHUB_ENV
      - uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: locustbuild
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: locustio/locust:${{ env.TAG }}${{ ( env.BRANCH == 'master' && ',locustio/locust:latest') || '' }}
```

(note that this will probably break if a tag is on master *and* another branch too)