# How to get current branch name in push AND pull_request events?

Tags: github, github-actions

In my Github Action, I need to clone another repo on the same branch as the one that triggered the workflow.

So if that was a push to `master`, then I need to clone the remote repo on the `master` branch.

And if it was a pull request from the `feature/xxx-yyy` branch, I need to symmetrically clone the remote repo on the `feature/xxx-yyy` branch.

I reckon I can use `${GITHUB_HEAD_REF}` in the case of `pull_request`, but it seems it won't work with `push.`

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: 'my-org/e2e-tests'
          ref: ${GITHUB_HEAD_REF}
          token: '${{ secrets.CI_PAT }}'
          path: 'e2e'
```

Any bits of advice on how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current branch within Github Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-the-current-branch-within-github-actions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60302058