# How to Extract Branch Name on Delete Event Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to extract the branch name on a delete event. Turns out it's not in the GITHUB_REF object as that will be the `default branch`.

Ordinarily I would run

```
- name: Extract branch name
  shell: bash
  run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
  id: extract_branch
```

But apparently with delete events I need to extract the branch via `${{ github.event.ref }}`

```
- name: Extract branch name
  shell: bash
  run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${{ github.event.ref }})" # how to drop refs/heads/?
  id: extract_branch
```

now I don't know how to drop the refs/heads aspect of the branch name.

EDIT: Since in the delete event case, `github.event.ref` already contains the simple branch name e.g. `feature-1-my-branch` and not `refs/heads/feature-1-my-branch` my example code above works.

In the event I want to do some post-processing on this context in a different event type, where `github.event.ref` returns `refs/heads/feature-1-my-branch` how would I drop the `refs/heads` in that case?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-current-branch-within-github-actions

Comment: That's not the same thing, as that's specifically about getting the branch name from the env variable `GITHUB_REF`. My question is about how to extract the branch name from `github.event.ref`. This wasn't a good example since in the delete event, `github.event.ref` has the simple branch name. But if I was in a different event, how would I drop the prefix `refs/heads` from this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `${{ github.event.ref }}` to reference the branch name, the full `delete` event payload is documented in the [GitHub API docs](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/event-payloads/#delete).

I also did a test myself. With workflow defined in [here](https://github.com/chenrui333/github-action-test/blob/feb56d132c8142995b8fea6fd67bdd914e5e0d68/.github/workflows/delete-event.yml).

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: run build
        run: |
          echo "GITHUB_SHA is ${{ github.sha }}"
          echo "GITHUB_REF is ${{ github.ref }}"
          echo "${{ github.event.ref }} - ${{ github.event.ref_type }}"
```

I can trigger a run by pushing and deleting a `branch` (it would also apply for `tag` as well). It leads to a run like [this](https://github.com/chenrui333/github-action-test/runs/846575945).

```
GITHUB_SHA is feb56d132c8142995b8fea6fd67bdd914e5e0d68
GITHUB_REF is refs/heads/master
so-62779643-test-delete-event-test2 - branch
```

[update]

For strip out the prefix in `GITHUB_REF`, here is what I did:

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: run build
        run: |
          echo "::set-env name=GITHUB_REF::${{ github.ref }}"
          echo "old GITHUB_REF is $GITHUB_REF"
          GITHUB_REF=$(echo $GITHUB_REF | sed -e "s#refs/heads/##g")
          echo "new GITHUB_REF is $GITHUB_REF"
```

[run log reference](https://github.com/chenrui333/github-action-test/runs/846717465)

```
old GITHUB_REF is refs/heads/master
new GITHUB_REF is master
```

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that myself in the docs that it's just the simple-ref on delete events and not the full one. Though it looks like `github.event.ref` is sometimes the full ref. I wonder how to manipulate github context data if I were to need to drop a prefix for a different event type.

Comment: Updated the original post to include the prefix strip script.