# How do I make a GitHub Action matrix element conditional?

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have a workflow that uses `'strategy' = 'matrix'` along with a list of specific configurations to build.

Here is my workflow file:

```yaml
#
# build-N-test-v2.1-Dev and build-N-test-v2.1-Release are nearly
# identical, but a few tests are commented out (to not needlessly stress CI system)
# for v2.1-Dev builds
#
# NOTE: I've tried many tricks - none which seem to work - to get this working on one file with one
# workflow and tests
#     https://github.community/t/what-is-the-correct-if-condition-syntax-for-checking-matrix-os-version/16221
#     https://github.community/t/how-to-conditionally-include-exclude-items-in-matrix-eg-based-on-branch/16853
#
# but none seem to work
#

name: build-N-test-v2.1-Dev

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - v2.1-Dev
      #- v2.1-Release
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      ignored:
        description: "ignored"
        required: false
        default: ""

## NB: JOBS section IDENTICAL between v2.1-Dev and 2.1-Release files EXCEPT that on v2.1-Dev file
## comment out all entries marked with includeInDevBranchBuilds: false
jobs:
  build-n-test-Linux:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.runs_on }}
    strategy:
      #
      # Configuration notes
      #   o --debug-symbols false to reduce build disk size (and we aren't debugging anyhow) in many debug configurations
      #
      matrix:
        include:
          # ## SADLY: Container operations are only supported on Linux runners
          # - displayTargetName: windows-DBG
          #   os: windows
          #   compiler: g++-8
          #   runs_on: windows-latest
          #   container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-windows-cygwin-vs2k19
          #   cpp_version: c++17
          #   config_name: Debug
          #   extra_config_args: --apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable

          ## centos 8
          - displayTargetName: centos-8
            os: unix
            compiler: g++
            runs_on: ubuntu-latest
            container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-centos-8-small
            cpp_version: c++17
            config_name: Release
            extra_config_args: --apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable
            includeInDevBranchBuilds: true

          ## ubuntu 18.04
          - displayTargetName: ubuntu-18.04-g++-8 (Debug)
            os: unix
            compiler: g++-8
            runs_on: ubuntu-latest
            container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu1804-regression-tests
            cpp_version: c++17
            config_name: Debug
            extra_config_args: --apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable --debug-symbols false
            includeInDevBranchBuilds: true

          - displayTargetName: ubuntu-18.04-cross-compile-raspberrypi (Debug)
            os: unix
            compiler: g++-8
            runs_on: ubuntu-latest
            container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu1804-regression-tests
            cpp_version: c++17
            config_name: Debug
            extra_config_args: --apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable --compiler-driver arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-8 --cross-compiling true
            includeInDevBranchBuilds: true

          # ubuntu 20.04
          # - displayTargetName: ubuntu-20.04-g++-9 (Debug)
          #   os: unix
          #   compiler: g++-9
          #   runs_on: ubuntu-latest
          #   container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests
          #   cpp_version: c++17
          #   config_name: Debug
          #   extra_config_args: --apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable --debug-symbols false
          #   includeInDevBranchBuilds: false

          # - displayTargetName: ubuntu-20.04-g++-10 (Debug)
          #   os: unix
          #   compiler: g++-10
          #   runs_on: ubuntu-latest
          #   container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests
          #   cpp_version: c++17
          #   config_name: Debug
          #   extra_config_args: --apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable --debug-symbols false
          #   includeInDevBranchBuilds: false

          - displayTargetName: ubuntu-20.04-g++-10
            os: unix
            compiler: g++-10
            runs_on: ubuntu-latest
            container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests
            cpp_version: c++17
            config_name: Release
            extra_config_args: --apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable
            includeInDevBranchBuilds: true

          # - displayTargetName: ubuntu-20.04-g++-10-c++2a
          #   os: unix
          #   compiler: g++-10
          #   runs_on: ubuntu-latest
          #   container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests
          #   cpp_version: c++2a
          #   config_name: Release
          #   extra_config_args: --apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable
          #   includeInDevBranchBuilds: false

          # - displayTargetName: ubuntu-20.04-clang++-10
          #   os: unix
          #   compiler: clang++-10
          #   runs_on: ubuntu-latest
          #   container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests
          #   cpp_version: c++17
          #   config_name: Release
          #   extra_config_args: --apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable
          #   includeInDevBranchBuilds: false

    ### ATTEMPT TO COMPRESS 2 workflow files into one, but so far not working
    ### SEE
    ### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384420/how-to-make-a-github-action-matrix-element-conditional/65385385#65385385
    ###
    #if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/v2.1-Release' || matrix.includeInDevBranchBuilds
    env:
      # vm has 2 virtual CPUs, but 8GB ram, so jobs=5 (empirical), and QUICK_BUILD avoids some internal testing
      MAKEFLAGS: "--jobs=3 QUICK_BUILD=1"
    container: ${{ matrix.container_image }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build System Info
        if: ${{ matrix.os=='unix' }}
        run: |
          lsb_release -d 2>/dev/null || true
          echo "CWD=" `pwd`
          echo "nproc=" `nproc`
          grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo | head -1
          grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
          grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
          df -h
      - name: Build System Info (Windows)
        if: ${{ matrix.os=='windows' }}
        run: |
          echo "CWD=" `pwd`
          df -h
      - name: Configure ${{ matrix.config_name }}
        run: |
          ./configure ${{ matrix.config_name }} --compiler-driver ${{ matrix.compiler }} ${{ matrix.extra_config_args }} --cppstd-version ${{ matrix.cpp_version }}
          cat ConfigurationFiles/${{ matrix.config_name }}.xml
      # Break out third-party-components to do clean so we dont run out of disk space, and break out TPC AND library
      # to show the summary time for each part
      - name: Make third-party-components
        run: |
          make third-party-components
          make clean
      - name: Make libraries
        run: make libraries
      - name: Make all
        run: make all
      - name: Run Tests
        run: make run-tests
      - name: Archive Samples Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Sample apps (${{ matrix.displayTargetName }})
          path: |
            Builds/${{ matrix.config_name }}/Samples-*
      - name: Archive Log Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Log Data (${{ matrix.displayTargetName }})
          path: |
            Builds/${{ matrix.config_name }}/PerformanceDump.txt
            /tmp/Trace*.txt

  build-n-test-MacOS:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.runs_on }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        # Add to extra_config_args for build speed: --Xerces no --OpenSSL no --lzma no --boost no
        include:
          - displayTargetName: MacOS-Debug
            os: macos-10.15
            runs_on: macos-10.15
            config_name: Debug
            extra_config_args: --apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable
            includeInDevBranchBuilds: true
          # - displayTargetName: MacOS
          #   os: macos-10.15
          #   runs_on: macos-10.15
          #   config_name: Release
          #   extra_config_args: --apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable
          #   includeInDevBranchBuilds: false
    env:
      # vm has 2 virtual CPUs, but 8GB ram, so jobs=5 (empirical), and QUICK_BUILD avoids some internal testing
      MAKEFLAGS: "--jobs=3 QUICK_BUILD=1"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build System Info
        run: |
          echo "CWD: `pwd`"
          df -h
          system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
          sw_vers
      # If we had docker ability, most of these would be built into a docker file
      - name: Install Basic Build requirements
        run: |
          brew install gnu-sed
          brew install p7zip
          brew install automake
          make install-realpath
      - name: Configure
        run: |
          ./configure ${{ matrix.config_name }} ${{ matrix.extra_config_args }}
          cat ConfigurationFiles/${{ matrix.config_name }}.xml
      - name: Build third-party-components
        run: |
          make third-party-components
          make clean
      - name: Build Library
        run: |
          make libraries
      - name: Build All
        run: |
          make all
      - name: Run-Tests
        run: |
          make run-tests
      - name: Workaround GitHub-Actions-MacOS Issue with env.TMPDIR
        run: |
          mkdir /tmp/LOGS-ARCHIVE
          cp $TMPDIR/Trace*.txt /tmp/LOGS-ARCHIVE
      - name: DEBUG Workaround GitHub-Actions-MacOS Issue with env.TMPDIR
        run: |
          echo "TMPDIR=$TMPDIR"
          echo "TMPDIR using ENV.TMPDIR=${{ env.TMPDIR }}"
          # Just the echo line above shows empty, and then the ls line causes exit 1/failure
          #ls -l ${{ env.TMPDIR }}/Trace*.txt
          #if this gets fixed, then lose Workaround GitHub-Actions-MacOS, and directly reference ${{ env.TMPDIR }}/Trace*.txt in Archive Log Results
      - name: Build System Info
        run: |
          df -h
      - name: Archive Log Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Log Results (${{ matrix.displayTargetName }})
          path: |
            Builds/${{ matrix.config_name }}/PerformanceDump.txt
            /tmp/LOGS-ARCHIVE
            #${{ env.TMPDIR }}/Trace*.txt
      - name: Archive Sample Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Samples (${{ matrix.displayTargetName }})
          path: |
            Builds/${{ matrix.config_name }}/Samples-*

  build-n-test-Windows:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.runs_on }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        # Add to extra_config_args for build speed: --Xerces no --OpenSSL no --lzma no --boost no
        include:
          - displayTargetName: windows-x86-Debug
            os: windows
            runs_on: windows-latest
            container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-windows-cygwin-vs2k19
            config_name: Debug
            extra_config_args: --arch x86 --apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable
            includeInDevBranchBuilds: true
          # - displayTargetName: windows-x86-Release
          #   os: windows
          #   runs_on: windows-latest
          #   container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-windows-cygwin-vs2k19
          #   config_name: Release
          #   extra_config_args: --arch x86 --apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable
          #   includeInDevBranchBuilds: false
          # - displayTargetName: windows-x86_64-Debug
          #   os: windows
          #   runs_on: windows-latest
          #   container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-windows-cygwin-vs2k19
          #   config_name: Debug
          #   extra_config_args: --arch x86_64 --apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable
          #   includeInDevBranchBuilds: false
          # - displayTargetName: windows-x86_64-Release
          #   os: windows
          #   runs_on: windows-latest
          #   container_image: sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-windows-cygwin-vs2k19
          #   config_name: Release
          #   extra_config_args: --arch x86 --apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable
          #   includeInDevBranchBuilds: false
    env:
      # vm has 2 virtual CPUs, but 8GB ram, so jobs=5 (empirical), and QUICK_BUILD avoids some internal testing
      MAKEFLAGS: "--jobs=3 QUICK_BUILD=1"
      ARTIFACTS_DIR: "c:/Artifacts/"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-current-branch-within-github-actions
      - name: Extract branch name
        shell: bash
        run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
        id: extract_branch
      - name: Build System Info
        shell: "bash"
        run: |
          echo "CWD: `pwd`"
          df -h
          systeminfo
          echo NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=$NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
      - name: docker pull ${{ matrix.container_image }}
        run: docker pull ${{ matrix.container_image }}
      - name: Start docker build environment
        run: |
          docker run --tty --memory 5G --cpus 2 --storage-opt 'size=50GB' --detach --name buildContainer ${{ matrix.container_image }}
      - name: Print Info about docker system
        shell: "bash"
        run: |
          docker ps -a
          docker exec buildContainer systeminfo
          docker exec buildContainer df -h
      - name: Git Checkout
        shell: "bash"
        run: |
          docker exec buildContainer sh -c "git clone https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika.git && cd Stroika && git checkout ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}"
      - name: Configure
        shell: "bash"
        run: |
          docker exec --workdir c:/Stroika buildContainer sh -c "./configure ${{ matrix.config_name }} ${{ matrix.extra_config_args }}"
          docker exec --workdir c:/Stroika buildContainer cat ConfigurationFiles/${{ matrix.config_name }}.xml
      - name: Build
        shell: "bash"
        run: |
          docker exec --workdir c:/Stroika --env MAKEFLAGS="$MAKEFLAGS" buildContainer make all
      - name: Run-Tests
        shell: "bash"
        run: |
          docker exec --workdir c:/Stroika --env MAKEFLAGS="$MAKEFLAGS" buildContainer make run-tests
      - name: Build System Info
        shell: "bash"
        run: |
          df -h
          docker exec buildContainer df -h
      - name: Copy Build Artifacts
        shell: "bash"
        # due to flaws in docker (windows must stop) - and cp no wildcards
        run: |
          docker exec --workdir c:/Stroika buildContainer bash -c 'mkdir TRACE_LOGS && cp $TEMP/Trace*.txt TRACE_LOGS/'
          docker stop buildContainer
          docker cp buildContainer:Stroika/Builds/${{ matrix.config_name }}/ $ARTIFACTS_DIR 2> /dev/null
          docker cp buildContainer:Stroika/TRACE_LOGS $ARTIFACTS_DIR 2> /dev/null
          rm -rf $ARTIFACTS_DIR/{ThirdPartyComponents,Tests,*.lib}
      - name: Archive Log Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Log Results (${{ matrix.displayTargetName }})
          path: |
            ${{ env.ARTIFACTS_DIR }}PerformanceDump.txt
            ${{ env.ARTIFACTS_DIR }}TRACE_LOGS
      - name: Archive Sample Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Samples (${{ matrix.displayTargetName }})
          path: |
            ${{ env.ARTIFACTS_DIR }}Samples-*
```

However, I'd like to **only** build some of the configurations **only** when the branch is `v2.1-Release`. That is - for the most part - just build one or two configurations but build a bunch more on release.

I've accomplished this by cloning the script (workflow) and renaming a few things and commenting things out, but it would be nice if the mechanism worked with matrix elements.

I realize there is an `if` feature that can be added to each step, but that would create tons of jobs with disabled steps. What I want is to not spin up those jobs at all for each matrix element that has the `if` part evaluates false.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

TLDR: you can do what you want with **one** workflow by filtering the configurations you want to use in a prior build job/step, and using the result of that filtering as the matrix value in your `build-n-test` job.

---

Longer version:

You can create a `job` (i.e. *build-n-test*) where the value of `strategy.matrix` is different based off of some criteria by setting the value of `strategy.matrix` to the deserialized `output` of a previous job (i.e. *matrix_prep*). This previous job would have the responsibility of constructing the `matrix` value as per your custom criteria. The following yaml demonstrates this (a copy has been included later on with comments added in for explanation):

```yaml
name: Configurable Build Matrix

on: push
jobs:
  matrix_prep:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
    - name: Check out code into the Go module directory
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - id: set-matrix
      run: |
        branchName=$(echo '${{ github.ref }}' | sed 's,refs/heads/,,g')  
        matrix=$(jq --arg branchName "$branchName" 'map( 
            . | select((.runOn==$branchName) or (.runOn=="always"))
        )' matrix_includes.json)                
        echo "matrix={\"include\":$(echo $matrix)}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  build-n-test:
    needs: matrix_prep
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.runs_on }}
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.matrix_prep.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:    
    - run: echo "Hello ${{ matrix.someValue }}"
```

The contents of the `matrix_includes.json` file used in the set-matrix task can be found after this paragraph. **To see what the matrix configuration from the question would look like as JSON, please look near the bottom of this answer.** I went the route of having a JSON file separate from the workflow definition itself because I found that including the raw JSON in the workflow itself was very messy (especially if the JSON file was large).

```json
[
    {
        "runs_on":"ubuntu-16.04",
        "someValue":"Foo",
        "runOn":"always"
    },
    {
        "runs_on":"ubuntu-18.04",
        "someValue":"Bar",
        "runOn":"v2.1-Release"
    },
    {
        "runs_on":"ubuntu-20.04",
        "someValue":"Hello again",
        "runOn":"v2.1-Release"
    }
]
```

Using the setup above, one configuration will be included for *all* builds, and two will only be included if the branch name matches *v2.1-Release*. With some tweaks to the `sed` and `jq` options in the Workflow file, the branch name restrictions could be made looser such that you could have configurations run for all branches that include `-Release` (instead of just for a single branch). I may include this in this answer if there is interest (as it does not necessarily match your current question).

### `set-matrix` Job Explanation

As far as the `set-matrix` task is concerned, please refer to the following notes:

```bash
# ${{ github.ref }} returns the full git ref. As such, 'refs/heads/` 
# should be stripped for easier future use.
branchName=$(echo '${{ github.ref }}' | sed 's,refs/heads/,,g')  
# Use jq to read in a json file that represents the matrix configuration. Each
# block has a 'runOn' property. The jq filter is setup to only output items that 
# are set to 'always' or that have a branch name that matches the current branch.
matrix=$(jq --arg branchName "$branchName" 'map(
  . | select((.runOn==$branchName) or (.runOn=="always")) 
)' matrix_includes.json)        
# This 'echo' uses a special syntax so that the output of this job 
# is set correctly.
echo "matrix={\"include\":$(echo $matrix)}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

### Workflow explanation

The following yaml content should be the same as above with some additional comments to help explain things:

```yaml
name: Configurable Build Matrix
on: push
jobs:
  matrix_prep:
    # Using a separate job and agent so as to be able to use tools 
    # like 'sed' and 'jq'.
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Defining outputs of a job allows for easier consumption and use.
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
    # Checking out code as the set-matrix step utilizes a 
    # file named matrix_includes.json.
    - name: Check out code into the Go module directory
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    # This step is explained more in a following section
    - id: set-matrix
      run: |
        branchName=$(echo '${{ github.ref }}' | sed 's,refs/heads/,,g')  
        matrix=$(jq --arg branchName "$branchName" 'map(
          . | select((.runOn==$branchName) or (.runOn=="always")) 
        )' matrix_includes.json)                
        echo "matrix={\"include\":$(echo $matrix)}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  build-n-test:
    # By stating 'needs' here, the output of 'matrix_prep' is 
    # available to this job.
    needs: matrix_prep
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.runs_on }}
    strategy:
      # We need to convert the json string output into an object that the 
      # GitHub Workflow expects. Thankfully, the json-schema for Workflows 
      # allows 'matrix' to be set to an expression.
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.matrix_prep.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
    # Output a configuration specific value as proof and as a sanity check
    - run: echo "Hello ${{ matrix.someValue }}"
```

## Demonstration

I put together two files for this demonstration:

- The [workflow definition](https://github.com/JoshuaTheMiller/StackOverflowAnswers/blob/main/.github/workflows/configurableBuildMatrix.yml) (pasted below)
- A [JSON file to contain matrix information](https://github.com/JoshuaTheMiller/StackOverflowAnswers/blob/main/matrix_includes.json) (pasted below)

The following two screenshots are from runs on different branches using the same workflow definition. Please note that the amount of build-n-test Jobs are different between the two:

*Build for main branch*
[image: Build for main branch]
*Build for v2.1-Release branch*
[image: Build for v2.1-Release branch]

This is due to the first build occurring on the `main` branch, and the second occurring on the `v2.1-Release` branch. As can be seen by the included `matrix_includes.json` file above, this is to be expected as two configurations are set to run *only* when the branch is `v2.1-Release`, and only one configuration is set to run *always*.

#### Further Detail

##### Matrix Configuration Filtering

The filtering is accomplished through using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to select objects from the json array that either have their `runOn` value set to `always` or that match the current `branchName`. This is the slight tweak to your logic that I mentioned earlier: instead of saying `includeInDevBranchBuilds`, I am using `runOn` as it seemed to work better for this specific example.

##### BranchName

The `set-matrix` step uses a value set from the previous line: `branchName=$(echo '${{ github.ref }}' | sed 's,refs/heads/.*-,,g')`. This line will strip `refs/heads/` from the branch ref and store the result in the value `branchName`. For example, if your branch is `2.1-Release`, `branchName` will be set to `2.1-Release`, and the filter from earlier will then match any objects that have `"runOn":"2.1-Release"` *or* `"runOn":"always"`.

##### The JSON file

The JSON file was created to simulate the **content** of the `includes` statement from the workflow that you linked. JSON is used as GitHub Actions have builtin JSON functions. As a sample, the following is my take on converting your `matrix:include` section to JSON. **Please note** that I've changed `includeInDevBranchBuilds` to be `runOn`, with the values set to either `always` or `v2.1-Release`.

```json
[
   {
      "displayTargetName": "centos-8",
      "os": "unix",
      "compiler": "g++",
      "runs_on": "ubuntu-latest",
      "container_image": "sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-centos-8-small",
      "cpp_version": "c++17",
      "config_name": "Release",
      "extra_config_args": "--apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable",
      "runOn": "always"
   },
   {
      "displayTargetName": "ubuntu-18.04-g++-8 (Debug)",
      "os": "unix",
      "compiler": "g++-8",
      "runs_on": "ubuntu-latest",
      "container_image": 
        "sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu1804-regression-tests",
      "cpp_version": "c++17",
      "config_name": "Debug",
      "extra_config_args": "--apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable",
      "runOn": "always"
   },
   {
      "displayTargetName": "ubuntu-20.04-g++-9 (Debug)",
      "os": "unix",
      "compiler": "g++-9",
      "runs_on": "ubuntu-latest",
      "container_image": 
        "sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests",
      "cpp_version": "c++17",
      "config_name": "Debug",
      "extra_config_args": "--apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable",
      "runOn": "v2.1-Release"
   },
   {
      "displayTargetName": "ubuntu-20.04-g++-10 (Debug)",
      "os": "unix",
      "compiler": "g++-10",
      "runs_on": "ubuntu-latest",
      "container_image": 
        "sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests",
      "cpp_version": "c++17",
      "config_name": "Debug",
      "extra_config_args": "--apply-default-debug-flags --trace2file enable",
      "runOn": "v2.1-Release"
   },
   {
      "displayTargetName": "ubuntu-20.04-g++-10",
      "os": "unix",
      "compiler": "g++-10",
      "runs_on": "ubuntu-latest",
      "container_image": 
        "sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests",
      "cpp_version": "c++17",
      "config_name": "Release",
      "extra_config_args": "--apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable",
      "runOn": "always"
   },
   {
      "displayTargetName": "ubuntu-20.04-g++-10-c++2a",
      "os": "unix",
      "compiler": "g++-10",
      "runs_on": "ubuntu-latest",
      "container_image": 
        "sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests",
      "cpp_version": "c++2a",
      "config_name": "Release",
      "extra_config_args": "--apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable",
      "runOn": "v2.1-Release"
   },
   {
      "displayTargetName": "ubuntu-20.04-clang++-10",
      "os": "unix",
      "compiler": "clang++-10",
      "runs_on": "ubuntu-latest",
      "container_image": 
         "sophistsolutionsinc/stroika-buildvm-ubuntu2004-regression-tests",
      "cpp_version": "c++17",
      "config_name": "Release",
      "extra_config_args": "--apply-default-release-flags --trace2file enable",
      "runOn": "v2.1-Release"
   }
]
```

Comment: @lewis, there is not an *easy built-in on/off* switch like what you describe for matrix builds today (Dec 29, 2020). However, you can accomplish the outcome that you describe as demonstrated [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434401/1542187). If a built-in option becomes available, I'll link to that answer when added

Comment: this was a REDICULOUSLY great! answer (in the sense that you were very clear about the why and how). SADLY, the answer is awefully complex. Im still not sure its worth changing my current process (duplicating the debug to the release config file and uncommenting lines). But maybe. PLEASE DO let me know if github ever addresses this in more straight-forward manner (like the on/off switch in each matrix element).

Comment: Maybe the last \" is not needed here?         echo ::set-output name=matrix::{\"include\":$(echo $matrix)}\"

Comment: Oooooh my this is hot. I didn't even think I could use `fromJson` and pass a dynamic value to matrix. This just changed everything.

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado You are right, the last `\n` is not correct (found out after using this examples for my own workflow). I editet the answer and removed it.

Answer (score 19):

I found this post and it was very helpful. Although, much more complex than the use-case I was having.

It lead me to explore other solutions and I came up with an alternative answer that works for simpler use-cases where you just want to exclude a single matrix dimension for certain conditions.

The examples will:

- Exclude `apple` if the current action is not run on `main` branch
- Exclude `banana` on PR builds if they don't have the `BUILD-BANANA` label applied

```yaml
strategy:
  matrix:
    fruit:
      - apple
      - banana
    exclude:
      - fruit: ${{ github.ref != 'refs/heads/main' && 'apple' }}
      - fruit: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && !contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'BUILD-BANANA') && 'banana' }}
```

Comment: This worked for me... but I had to change `&& '' || 'apple'` to `&& 'dummy' || 'apple'`.   Because `''` is "falsey" it caused `apple` to always be excluded.

Comment: If you invert the condition, you don't need the `dummy`. I edited the reply to simplify the sample.

Comment: That's great. I guess that implicitly resolves the excluded dimension to one called "false"?

Answer (score 10):

> I REALIZE there is an 'if' feature that can be added to each step, but that would create tons of jobs with disabled steps. What I want, is to just not spin up those jobs at all for each matrix element that has the if part evaluates false.

With [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows), we can skip the (reusable) *jobs* (vs each step) entirely, just by adding *single* condition to the (reusable) job/passing the flag as an input. Not an ideal as we still get the skipped jobs in the reports, but quite a dealbreaker, compared to conditionalizing every job step.

matrix-workflow.yml:

```
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        build-config:
          - foo: 'bar'
            if: ${{ xxx }}
          - foo: 'baz'
            if: ${{ yyy }}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml
    with:
      if: ${{ matrix.build-config.if }}
      foo: ${{ matrix.build-config.foo }}
```

reusable-workflow.yml:

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      if:
        description: 'Whether to run this job'
        required: false
        default: true
        type: boolean
      foo:
        required: true
        type: string
jobs:
  reusable-build:
    if: ${{ inputs.if }}
...
```

An example of the skipped job in the reports:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! Well, not the need for 'another layer of indirection', but that's an issue with GitHub Actions in general.

I found this because I was looking for a way to have a matrix of jobs which all 'skip' if they know that they don't need to do anything, but which can also be listed as 'required checks' in branch protection. If you set the skip to happen at the matrix level, the branch protection checks will never be satisfied. Doing it in the individual jobs works fine.

Small improvement: 'if' in the reusable workflow's job doesn't need "${{ }}" since it's an expression context.

Answer (score 9):

Adding another answer as this one uses [custom Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/conditional-build-matrix) instead of inline-shell scripts. Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of one of the Actions (thank you for the inspiration).

---

By using two additional actions,

- [JoshuaTheMiller/conditional-build-matrix](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/conditional-build-matrix)
- [nelonoel/branch-name](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-branch-name)

You can accomplish a similar effect that the [custom shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434401/1542187) in my other answer has, but in an arguably cleaner fashion:

*.github/workflows/sample.yml*

```yaml
name: Configurable Build Matrix

on: push
jobs:
  matrix_prep:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: nelonoel/branch-name@v1.0.1
      - id: set-matrix
        uses: JoshuaTheMiller/conditional-build-matrix@1.0.1       
        with:          
          filter: '[?runOn==`${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}` || runOn==`always`]'
  build-n-test:
    needs: matrix_prep
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.runs_on }}
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.matrix_prep.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
    - run: echo "Hello ${{ matrix.someValue }}"
```

*.github/workflows/matrix_includes.json*

```json
[
    {
        "runs_on":"ubuntu-16.04",
        "someValue":"Foo",
        "runOn":"always"
    },
    {
        "runs_on":"ubuntu-18.04",
        "someValue":"Bar",
        "runOn":"v2.1-Release"
    },
    {
        "runs_on":"ubuntu-20.04",
        "someValue":"Hello again",
        "runOn":"v2.1-Release"
    }
]
```

*both files can be found in the [repo of the Action](https://github.com/JoshuaTheMiller/conditional-build-matrix/tree/main/.github/workflows)*

### Notes

- The `filter` input uses a different filtering syntax as well: instead of jq, it uses [JMESPATH](https://jmespath.org/). I've found JMESPATH to be very well documented and supported. To learn more about how the sytax works, you can visit their [interactive examples page](https://jmespath.org/examples.html).
- By default, the `conditional-build-matrix` action looks for a file named `matrix_includes.json` under the `.github/workflows/` folder (the same file included in the other answer). This location can be customized, and is [documented on the Action's page](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/conditional-build-matrix#json-file-placement).

Comment: I get this error from your solution: The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/release.yml (Line: 22, Col: 15): Expected format {org}/{repo}[/path]@ref. Actual 'JoshuaTheMiller/conditional-build-matrix' Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @FernandoRojo, could you provide a link to your repo and/or open an issue on the GitHub Action if you believe there is an issue? As a quick sanity check, I reran the sample build that demonstrates this answer and it functioned correctly: https://github.com/JoshuaTheMiller/conditional-build-matrix/actions/runs/1023446413

Comment: I think it's because you used a local action, rather than import it from a separate repo. Try making a separate repo that imports your action, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @FernandoRojo I ran this from a different repo as a sanity check, and the [build completed successfully](https://github.com/JoshuaTheMiller/conditional-build-matrix-test/actions/runs/1121146407). 

Could you share a link to the build of yours that is failing?

Comment: I *just* updated this answer to include the version of my Action (`@0.0.1`) as it was missing in this answer before. Could this be the root of the issue you are seeing?

Answer (score -1):

What most people do not realise is that matrices, e.g. matrix configurations with "include" is much more usable&more complex than regular matrices. It is essential in Terraform for example,

Adding job#0 just to dynamically create "include" matrices is lame and will be spoiling visual - it is only reasonable if you have 1 pipe that doin' all envs and 1000 different VMs/K8S based on lame input.

What we need is to auto exclude include matrix config if there is only one correspondent env: dev, if we have only "dev" in envs list we Obviously want to skip all the rest but still github has the best pipe features.