# GitHub actions conditional config

Tags: r, github-actions

(GH newb attempting to [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) my way through some configuration ...)

I am using the GitHub actions YAML file [here](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/check-standard.yaml) to test an R package.  By default this workflow tests on four separate platforms, but this is overkill for my day-to-day needs. ([This action](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/check-release.yaml) does more limited testing, but I think? it also misses some stuff I wanted from the fuller workflow ...)

I would like to have the tests done on all four platforms **only if** the commit message includes the string "full check", otherwise testing just one platform. I know I can in principle achieve something like this if I include a conditional:

```
if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[full ci]')"
```

but I'm not sure of the precise syntax for including it in the workflow (and I'm afraid of spending many hours on trial-and-error attempts)

The chunk of the workflow that defines the set of platforms current looks like this, with three of the platforms commented out:

```
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
          - {os: ubuntu-20.04, r: 'release', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"}
##          - {os: ubuntu-20.04, r: 'devel', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"}
##          - {os: windows-latest, r: 'release'}
##          - {os: macOS-latest, r: 'release'}
```

I'm assuming that just sticking the `if:` clause below the first row won't work (because it would break up the list). I suppose something like this might work?

```
    matrix:
      config:
        if: "! contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[full ci]')"]
        config:
           - {os: ubuntu-20.04, r: 'release', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"}
        if: "contains(...)"
        config: 
            [list with all four configs]
```

(Does this syntax have an `if/else` construct?)

I'm looking for answers that help me achieve the narrow goal, and hopefully understand the YAML syntax a little better (I have tried to read the [FM](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) ...)

Comment: This is pretty similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384420/how-to-make-a-github-action-matrix-element-conditional. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Looks like it might be, thanks.  I will have to read and digest it (more complex/harder to adapt than I had hoped, but it looks like the right direction ...)  I would happily accept an answer that adapts [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65513159/190277) to my situation ('cause it will take me from tens of minutes to hours to grok the answer sufficiently to adapt it ...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a github action matrix element conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384420/how-to-make-a-github-action-matrix-element-conditional)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is not possible to add conditions to the matrix construct itself. You could generate the matrix data beforehand in another job and then use it in your job.

There is a simpler solution: Use two jobs, because `if` can be used at the job level. Copy the current job that you have and then add if-conditions to each job. Keep one job as it is for the full CI and in the other job hardcode your environment for the ordinary commits.

Something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  R-CMD-check-ordinary:
    if: ${{ ! contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[full ci]') }}
    # Hardcode os
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    # Hardcode name
    name: Test only on Ubuntu

    env:
      R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS: true
      RSPM: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    steps:
      # replace any occurences of matrix.config. with hardcoded values
      ...
      
  # And the original job
  R-CMD-check-full:
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[full ci]') }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}

    name: ${{ matrix.config.os }} (${{ matrix.config.r }})

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
          - {os: ubuntu-20.04, r: 'release', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"}
          - {os: ubuntu-20.04, r: 'devel', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"}
          - {os: windows-latest, r: 'release'}
          - {os: macOS-latest, r: 'release'}

    env:
      R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS: true
      RSPM: ${{ matrix.config.rspm }}
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    steps:
      ...
```

### Regarding YAML syntax:

YAML is a data format. Don't think of YAML as a script or program. A YAML file is similar to a list of command line arguments for a program. It only defines input data for another program.

So there is no `if` in YAML. For YAML `if: condition` is like as any other `key: value` pair, there is no logic attached.

Comment: this is a nice, simple answer. It violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) but may be worth it in this case.

Comment: I take your point as YAML being a data format. My comments about understanding the syntax were driven by frustration at my ignorance about the syntax and the importance of whitespace, meaning of elements with and without dashes, etc.

Comment: It think it helps to always keep in mind that although there are several ways to write them, there are just two data types, lists (a.k.a. arrays) and key-value-pairs (a.k.a. dictionaries/hash maps)