# Conditional value in github workflow

Tags: github-actions

My current github workflow as quite repeating code to allow a conditionnement in what and where releases should be pushed depending on the event type :

```
name: Build LaTeX document & latexdiff to previous tagged version.
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Build stuff
        ...
        ...
      - name: Upload results (master latest)
        uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: "latest"
          prerelease: true
          draft: true
          title: "Build"
          files: |
            result
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}
      - name: Upload results (pull request)
        uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: github.ref_name
          prerelease: true
          draft: true
          title: "Build"
          files: |
            result
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
      - name: Upload results (tag)
        uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: github.ref_name
          prerelease: false
          draft: false
          title: "Build"
          files: |
            result
        if: ${{ github.ref_type == 'tag' }}
```

Is there a way to conditontionally set values so that i dont have to repeat 3 times the same thing ? Basically i want to deal with the three different cases :

- Some commit lands on master, I releas it with the `latest` tag.
- Some tag lands on master, I release it with its propper tag.
- PRs are released under their names.

Not that it changes anything, but it really looks ugly to me.

Comment: Check the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384420/how-do-i-make-a-github-action-matrix-element-conditional) in this, similar to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the params as an [output of a step](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs) and then use them in the upload step:

```yaml
name: Build LaTeX document & latexdiff to previous tagged version.

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Build stuff
        ...
        
      - name: Set params
        id: params
        run: |
          if [[ "${{ github.event_name }}" -eq "push"  && "${{ github.ref }}" -eq "refs/heads/master" ]]; then
            echo "tag=latest" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "prerelease=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "draft=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          elif [[ "${{ github.event_name }}" -eq "pull_request" ]]; then
            echo "tag=${{ github.ref_name }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "prerelease=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "draft=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          elif [[ "${{ github.ref_type }}" -eq "tag" ]]; then
            echo "tag=${{ github.ref_name }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "prerelease=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "draft=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi

      - name: Upload results
        uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: ${{ steps.params.outputs.tag }}
          prerelease: ${{ steps.params.outputs.prerelease }}
          draft: ${{ steps.params.outputs.draft }}
          title: "Build"
          files: |
            result
```

Is it better then having 3 types of the step? I don't know. I have my doubts.

**Notes:**

- There is no default. In case it's possible that there is an additional GitHub event that doesn't match these cases, then either set it in the additional `else` Bash condition or introduce an `if` condition to the upload step to make sure that it runs only in one of the three scenarios.
- I haven't tested the code and there might be some bug. However, I believe you understand the idea of setting the params.

Comment: Looks like this is what i need indeed. Thanks a lot for taking the time, really helps.