# How to display GitHub action badge for current running branch?

Tags: github, github-actions

I need to show the GitHub action badge for the current running branch, instead, it is limited to one branch(default or specified).

Answer (score 2):

As the "[Adding a workflow status badge](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge)" mentions, displaying the status of a workflow run for a specific branch or event is only done using the `branch` and `event` query parameters in the URL.

But those parameters are fixed. Modifying them would mean updating the README every time a new action is running.

Said action can get the name of the branch it operates on (see "[How to get the current branch within GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58033366/6309)")

But you would then need to combine that action with, for instance, [`github-update-readme`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-update-readme) in order to include the right URL for the badge:

```
![example](https://github.com/github/docs/actions/workflows/main.yml/badge.svg?branch=${GH_BRANCH})
                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
                                       (value computed from the previous step by your main action)
```

Comment: ${GH_BRANCH} not work for me in README.me

Comment: @Ali.MD Did you find any other variable that would work in your case?