# Get the head ref branch name in GitHub Actions when PR is merged to main branch

Tags: github-actions

I want to trigger a GitHub Actions workflow when a **release/vX.Y.Z** format of PR gets merged into the **main** branch.

I want the version number from this head branch i.e. "**vX.Y.Z**" so that I can create a release and tag it accordingly.

```yaml
name: Auto PR Action

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - main
    types: [closed]
  

jobs:
  build:
    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Extract version number
        run: |
          echo "${{ github.event.pull_request.base_ref }}"

          # Extract version number from the Release branch format: release/v1.2.3
          # E.g: release/v1.2.3 | sed 's/.*\///' will give us v1.2.3

          echo "${{ GET_THE_RELEASE_BRANCH_NAME }}" | sed 's/.*\///' >> $RELEASE_VERSION

      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: |
          gh release create $RELEASE_VERSION --generate-notes --latest --verify-tag
```

I always get the information about the base branch, i.e. main, but no info about the head branch.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current branch within Github Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-the-current-branch-within-github-actions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to trigger a GitHub Actions workflow when a release/vX.Y.Z format of PR gets merged into the main branch.

Here is something similar using the `release-vX.Y.Z` format:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  tag:
    if: contains(github.head_ref, 'release-') && contains(github.base_ref, 'main') && github.event.action == 'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      tag: ${{ steps.tag.outputs.tag }}
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch tag
        id: tag
        run: |
          BRANCH=${{ github.head_ref }}
          TAG="${BRANCH//release-/""}"
          echo $TAG
          echo "tag=$TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  release:
    needs:
      - TAG
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      TAG: ${{ needs.TAG.outputs.tag }}
    steps:
       [ ... ] # use $TAG to do something
```

This workflow will trigger when a PR is closed.

However, according to the `if` expression, the `tag` job will only be executed when the PR head branch use the `release-vX.Y.Z` format, and if the PR gets merged into the `main` branch.

Using this implementation, the `tag` variable and `output` will be equal to `vX.Y.Z`.

- [Personal workflow implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/61-create-tag-and-release.yml)
- [Workflow runs](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/workflows/61-create-tag-and-release.yml)