# Variable for branch name in GitHub Action

Tags: git, github, github-actions

When using GitHub Actions, is it possible to use a variable for the branch name?

I want to specify the branch name in on > push > branches, but I also want to use it later on in my job, so I am just trying to avoid duplication.

I am using this setup:

```yaml
name: 'Build and deploy'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - my-branch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - my-branch
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  GITHUB_BRANCH: 'my-branch'
```

Doing the following gets marked as an error:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - ${{ env.GITHUB_BRANCH }} # Unrecognized named-value: env
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - ${{ env.GITHUB_BRANCH }} # Unrecognized named-value: env
  workflow_dispatch:
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current branch within Github Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-the-current-branch-within-github-actions)

Comment: No, it does not. I want to set and use a variable, not get the current branch.

Comment: if the event trigger is configured to only run on pushes to a certain branch then `github.ref_name` will always be equal to that branch name.

Comment: @TonyArra Does that also apply to pull requests? (I have updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

How about like this?

```
name: 'Build and deploy'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - my-branch
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  GITHUB_BRANCH: ${{ github.ref_name }}
```

That leaves the config in one place, so it reduces the duplication like you want.  Instead of `branches` referencing the environment variable, the environment variable references the branch, but you still have the branch defined in just one place.

Comment: Nice idea, but will this work with pull requests?  (I have updated the question)

Comment: The updated question is something different than what it was when I answered.  I question why you would want to trigger on both pull requests and pushes to the same branch?  Usually those are triggered on _different_ branches--where a pull request is made to pull changes from one branch into another.  So while the updated question changes things in an theoretical way, in typical usage scenarios I think the branch names will be different anyway.  Otherwise, a PR that triggers a run will occur after a push has already triggered a run on the same code--which would be redundant.