# Is there a way to have the name of the source branch in the push event in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a `main` branch in GitHub.
and create a new branch like `git checkout -b my-branch`
Then I open a pull request from `my-branch` to the `main` branch

I have this GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: ["_.//"]

jobs:
  test:
    name: test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise ]
    steps:
      - name: echo
        runs: |
          echo "?" # I want to echo `my-branch` if it was a pull request from the `my-branch` branch. else if it is a direct push, echo `direct`
```

I want to echo `my-branch` if it was a pull request from the `my-branch` branch else if it is a direct push, echo `direct`

Is there a way to do that?

I tried this workflow:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: ["_.//"]

jobs:
  test:
    name: test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise ]
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: |
          echo "branch=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}}"
```

- once it was triggered on `my-branch`, it echoed `branch=my-branch`
- once I opened a pull request from `my-branch` to the `main` branch and then merged that pull request, it was triggered on the main branch and it returned `branch=main`

This is not what I am looking for.

What I am looking for is that once I open a pull request from `my-branch` to the `main` branch and then merge that pull request, and then it runs on the main branch, it echoes `branch=my-branch`

---

update:
finally I decided to do this

```
name: test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "**"
      - "!main"
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - "main"

jobs:
  test:
    name: test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise ]
    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: |
          echo "branch=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}}"
```

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035262/7976758 ? Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-actions%5D+branch+name

Comment: I am looking for the source branch name. The pipeline is running on the `main` branch but I want to echo `my-branch`

Comment: and the pipeline is triggered on the push event

Comment: Did you look at what's exposed to your job already? E.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

Comment: @AminBa The `head_ref` is the source branch of the pull request.

Comment: let me try that in a test workflow and let you know

Comment: please read my updated question in which I have shared the result of my test

Comment: Why was it "triggered on the main branch"? Notice that your current triggers overlap: a push into a branch that has an open PR will trigger both `push` and `pull_request`. Also, what's the relevance of that branch filter on `_.//`?

Comment: see my workflow. I am not allowing it on pull_request.   pull_request:
    branches: ["_.//"]

Comment: A push doesn't _have_ a "source branch". That's meaningless for push events, which are just for _a commit_. Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77277438/how-do-i-know-the-source-branch-name-for-a-merge#comment136238740_77277438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment, given *"The pipeline is running on the main branch"* *"and the pipeline is triggered on the **push** event"* (bold by me), then there is no source branch any longer.

You only have a source branch when there is a pull request.

You would therefore need to provide this missing information through a different channel, the actions build environment does not suffice.

Comment: Even in the context of a pull request, the terminology (and variable names) use "head" and "base" branch, where you merge the head branch into the base branch.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, absolutely, not to mention the many refs that are then there on Github. What is perhaps useful is a link to the manual for the workflow events as they lead to the resulting action build environments: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows - this should lead to the various bridges and  partings of the ways into branches.