# Obtain branch name in github action (on pull request)

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, cicd

I have a github action that is triggered upon a pull request. I want to obtain the name of the branch whose pull request is created. For example "adding-new-columns"

```
name: Test
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]

jobs:
  print-branch-name:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Print Branch Name
        run: echo "${"$GITHUB_REF"}"
```

However,

"$GITHUB_REF" gives me:

```
refs/pull/24/merge
```

Is it possible to obtain the actual branch name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current branch within Github Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-the-current-branch-within-github-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `GITHUB_HEAD_REF` that you are looking for but only works for pull request. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables

GITHUB_HEAD_REF -> source branch

GITHUB_BASE_REF -> target branch