# Extract a substring (value of an HTML node tag) in a bash/zsh script

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm trying to extract a tag value of an HTML node that I already have in a variable.
I'm currently using Zsh but I'm trying to make it work in Bash as well.

The current variable has the value:

```
<span class="alter" fill="#ffedf0" data-count="0" data-more="none"/>
```

and I would like to get the value of **data-count** (in this case 0, but could be any length integer).

I have tried using cut, sed and the variables expansion as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482123/extract-part-of-a-string-using-bash-cut-split) but I haven't managed to adapt the regexs, or maybe it has to be done differently for Zsh.

Comment: Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why `sed` would not work in this situation. For your specific case, I would do something like this:

```
sed 's/.*data-count="\([0-9]*\)".*/\1/g' file_name.txt
```

Basically, it just states that `sed` is looking for the a pattern that contains `data-count=`, then saves everything within the paranthesis `\(...\)` into `\1`, which is subsequently printed in place of the match (full line due to the `.*`)

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/data-count=[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-13)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `match` function of `awk` to match regex `data-count=[^ ]*` means match everything from data-count till a space comes, if this regex is TRUE(a match is found) then out of the box variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` will be set. Later I am printing current line's sub-string as per these variables values to get only value of `data-count`.

---

With `sed` could you please try following.

```
sed 's/.*data-count=\"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sed`'s capability of group referencing and saving regex value in first group after `data-count=\"` which is its length, then since using `s`(substitution) with `sed` so mentioning `1`  will replace all with `\1`(which is matched regex value in temporary memory, group referencing).

Comment: Just checked and adapting to a pipe in the script both awk and sed work in zsh and bash. I will mark the first one as the correct answer since it also works fine.

Comment: @CarlosAS, Np, I am happy that I am able to help you, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As was said before, to be on the safe side and handle any syntactically valid HTML tag, a parser would be strongly advised. But if you know in advance, what the general format of your HTML element will look like, the following hack might come handy:

Assume that your variable is called "html"

```
html='<span class="alter" fill="#ffedf0" data-count="0" data-more="none"/>'
```

First adapt it a bit:

```
htmlx="tag ${html%??}"
```

This will add the string *tag* in front and remove the final `/>`

Now make an associative array:

```
declare -A fields
fields=( ${=$(tr = ' ' <<<$htmlx)} )
```

The *tr* turns the equal sign into a space and the `${=` handles word splitting. You can now access the values of your attributes by, say,

```
echo $fields[data-count]
```

Note that this still has the surrounding double quotes. Yuo can easily remove them by

```
echo ${${fields[data-count]%?}#?}
```

Of course, once you do this hack, you have access to all attributes in the same way.