# How to split the variable in Gitlab pipline (.gitlab-ci.yml)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a branch name, for example, release-1.1.3, how I can split and extract the version by writing some logic in gitlab-ci file. Is there some method available for it?

**before_script**

- export BRANCH_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

  // here I want to do something to extract the version
- export Major=BRANCH_NAME.someoperation
- export Minor=BRANCH_NAME.someoperation
- export PATCH=BRANCH_NAME.someoperation

any other approaches are also welcome but I required the value in a separate variable which I can pass it to other operations.

I am new to gitlab-ci and working on it, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to split your string Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397698/how-to-cut-a-string-after-a-specific-character-in-unix

Comment: Thanks bro.. able to resolve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cut a string after a specific character in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397698/how-to-cut-a-string-after-a-specific-character-in-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split your string

You will find some examples here.

[How to cut a string after a specific character in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397698/how-to-cut-a-string-after-a-specific-character-in-unix)